# Why check both isset() and !empty()

Tags: php

Is there a difference between `isset` and `!empty`. If I do this double boolean check, is it correct this way or redundant? and is there a shorter way to do the same thing?

```
isset($vars[1]) AND !empty($vars[1])
```

Comment: There is a nice chart on the results of using them with different types of variables (they do have differences) here: https://www.virendrachandak.com/demos/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null.php

Comment: The obvious exact complements are isset and is_null, but !empty covers a few different ones. It all depends on the type of data you are testing for.

Answer (score 462, accepted):

This is completely redundant. `empty` is more or less shorthand for `!isset($foo) || !$foo`, and `!empty` is analogous to `isset($foo) && $foo`. I.e. `empty` does the reverse thing of `isset` plus an additional check for the *truthiness* of a value.

Or in other words, `empty` is the same as `!$foo`, but doesn't throw warnings if the variable doesn't exist. That's the main point of this function: do a boolean comparison without worrying about the variable being set.

[The manual](http://php.net/empty) puts it like this:

> `empty()` is the opposite of `(boolean) var`, **except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set.**

You can simply use `!empty($vars[1])` here.

Comment: But then if there is no `$vars[1]` he'll get a notice.

Comment: I've no idea where I got that idea from. Plus one'd.

Comment: @karim IMO `empty` is one of the most misunderstood functions in PHP. The tiny snippet about "no warning is generated" is very easy to overlook. I had to scan the documentation myself a few times to spot it to post it here.

Comment: `empty($vars[1])` doesn't cause any warnings even `$vars[1]` is not set, but `echo $vars[1]` will. I checked the fact using `echo $vars[1]; if (!empty($vars[1])) echo 1; else echo 0;`.

Comment: @AmilWaduwawara - Yes. Your snippet behaves as expected, you star with an echo statement. I imagine you get the warning then the 0.

Comment: Most answers here are wrong as far as I can tell.  The 2 are not the same when a variable is set AND empty. `isset` returns true and `empty` returns false.  Doesn't matter if it's a string or an array.  So any test that wants to know if a variable exists and is not empty, or the opposite, needs to use both

Comment: @fred Uhm, no. The "isset and empty" ("isset *but* empty") is covered by `isset($var) && !$var`. But this test also has a false negative if you're testing the value `null`, so is not reliable and therefore largely not applicable in practice. What you write at the end, "exists and is not empty", is simply `!empty`. I'm not sure what exactly "the opposite" is, so here's both: "not exists and is empty" → `!isset` (again: false negatives), "not exists or is empty" → `empty`.

Comment: @fred Always write out `empty` in its logical long form `!isset($var) || $var == false` and you'll see that it's *always* redundant in any combination of `isset` together with `empty`.

Comment: Except it doesn't really work because when your value is 0 it is considered as empty and its obviously not the case. 

So thanks PHP for having a good API, I guess. #not

Comment: @Shahor That *works* as intended. That `0` is a falsey value in PHP is something you have to be aware of, it's not just `empty` that treats it that way.

Comment: @deceze I know it works that way, I just don't like that fact in the language.

Comment: @Shahor *Many* languages regard `0` as `false`. PHP isn't the only one. Still not sure what your complaint is.

Comment: `empty()` will *still* throw a warning for nested variables. For instance, this code will throw a warning: `empty($unsetvar1[$unsetvar2['test']]);`

Comment: @karim79 @deceze I think that at one point, using `empty` on a variable that didn't exist would have generated a warning. In the mid 2000s to the early 2010s, a lot of PHP code that I worked on used `isset(var) && !empty(var)` as a truth test. In fact I did that out of habit for so long that I arrived at this page today while searching to make sure I didn't need to anymore.

Comment: @felwithe I just looked at the PHP 4 & 3 manuals, and even they already mention `empty` not generating any warnings.

Comment: This is simply not true and the accepted answer should be ignored! Learn more: https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-to-check-both-isset-and-empty-function-in-php/

Comment: @madjoe You'll have to be more specific what exactly "isn't true" here.

Comment: @deceze I suggest to delete the first sentence where the author of the proposed answer suggests isset and !empty as redundant, which is not the case. Later he explains the correlation between the two, but someone may get the impression we should choose only one to avoid "redundancy". Check both links in my comment above.

Comment: @madjoe The question is whether one should use `isset() && !empty()` *together*. And the correct answer is that this is entirely redundant. Not sure what you're against exactly.

Comment: @deceze: If you use `isset($var) && !empty($var)` and if we assign any one of the following elements to $var = {” ” (space), TRUE, NULL byte (“\ 0”)}, it will always return TRUE. On the other hand, `isset()` alone would return TRUE for different and a bigger set of values for $var. Therefore, how could it be redundant?

Comment: @madjoe Because the `!empty` check is a superset of what `isset` does. You're essentially checking `isset($var) && isset($var) && $var != false`. And that's redundant. You can leave out the `isset`.

Comment: @deceze: Ok, you are right. I completely misunderstood your point from the beginning, I apologize.

Comment: isset() can be lenght 0 and returns true, but !empty() check has some value in it ...so is good to have both. when you are passing variables via post for example

Comment: @vincentthorpe It’s good to have both functions available, sure, but there’s never a case where using them together makes any sense.

Comment: @deceze when it comes to arrays it still shows `Notice` : https://i.imgur.com/hctFlnz.png OR am I missing something?

Comment: @Binod Can’t say anything about that from that screenshot alone.

Comment: @deceze `!empty` to an undefined key of an array really is throwing `Notice` which seems we need to use `isset($vars[1]) AND !empty($vars[1])` instead of just `!empty($vars[1])` right?

Comment: @Binod That should not be the case. Please provide a self-contained example, e.g. at http://3v4l.org. I’d guess you have a custom error handler which gets invoked (yes, even when using `empty`), which is indiscriminately producing exceptions.

Comment: @deceze There is a logical error in that line itself. lol. https://i.imgur.com/hctFlnz.png. This first `empty` actually doesnt just wrap the array reference. :)

Answer (score 35):

`isset()` tests if a variable is set and not null:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

`empty()` can return true when the variable is set to certain values:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

To demonstrate this, try the following code with $the_var unassigned, set to 0, and set to 1.

```
<?php

#$the_var = 0;

if (isset($the_var)) {
  echo "set";
} else {
  echo "not set";
}

echo "\n";

if (empty($the_var)) {
  echo "empty";
} else {
  echo "not empty";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 22):

`isset($vars[1]) AND !empty($vars[1])` is equivalent to `!empty($vars[1])`.

I prepared simple code to show it empirically.

Last row is undefined variable.

```
+-----------+---------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| Var value | empty() | isset() | !empty() | isset() && !empty() |
+-----------+---------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| ''        | true    | true    | false    | false               |
| ' '       | false   | true    | true     | true                |
| false     | true    | true    | false    | false               |
| true      | false   | true    | true     | true                |
| array ()  | true    | true    | false    | false               |
| NULL      | true    | false   | false    | false               |
| '0'       | true    | true    | false    | false               |
| 0         | true    | true    | false    | false               |
| 0.0       | true    | true    | false    | false               |
| undefined | true    | false   | false    | false               |
+-----------+---------+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

And code

```
$var1 = "";
$var2 = " ";
$var3 = FALSE;
$var4 = TRUE;
$var5 = array();
$var6 = null;
$var7 = "0";
$var8 = 0;
$var9 = 0.0;

function compare($var)
{
    print(var_export($var, true) . "|" .
        var_export(empty($var), true) . "|" .
        var_export(isset($var), true) . "|" .
        var_export(!empty($var), true) . "|" .
        var_export(isset($var) && !empty($var), true) . "\n");
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $var = 'var' . $i;
    compare($$var);
}

@print(var_export($var10, true) . "|" .
    var_export(empty($var10), true) . "|" .
    var_export(isset($var10), true) . "|" .
    var_export(!empty($var10), true) . "|" .
    var_export(isset($var10) && !empty($var10), true) . "\n");
```

Undefined variable must be evaluated outside function, because function itself create temporary variable in the scope itself.

Answer (score 13):

isset() is **NOT** equivalent to !empty().

You will create some rather unpleasant and hard to debug bugs if you go down this route. e.g. try running this code:

```
<?php

$s = '';

print "isset: '" . isset($s) . "'. ";
print "!empty: '" . !empty($s) . "'";

?>
```

https://3v4l.org/J4nBb

Answer (score 8):

```
$a = 0;
if (isset($a)) { //$a is set because it has some value ,eg:0
    echo '$a has value';
}
if (!empty($a)) { //$a is empty because it has value 0
    echo '$a is not empty';
} else {
    echo '$a is empty';
}
```

Comment: But you haven't handled variable not set case.

Answer (score 3):

Empty just check is the refered variable/array has an value if you check the [php doc(empty)](https://www.php.net/empty) you'll see this things are considered emtpy

> ```
> * "" (an empty string)
> * 0 (0 as an integer)
> * "0" (0 as a string)
> * NULL
> * FALSE
> * array() (an empty array)
> * var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
> ```

while isset check if the variable isset and not null which can also be found in the [php doc(isset)](http://php.net/isset)

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary.

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. **That means
>   empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var)** || $var
>   == false.

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: This has never been necessary on any PHP version, since empty already checks for (not) isset. You are confusing the fact that empty now supports expressions with the question.

Comment: It is only true, five years later.

Answer (score 1):

- From the PHP Web site, referring to the `empty()` function:

Returns `FALSE` if `var` has a non-empty and non-zero value.

That’s a good thing to know. In other words, everything from `NULL`, to `0` to “” will return `TRUE` when using the `empty()` function.

- Here is the description of what the `isset()` function returns:

Returns `TRUE` if `var` exists; `FALSE` otherwise.

In other words, only variables that don’t exist (or, variables with strictly `NULL` values) will return `FALSE` on the `isset()` function. All variables that have any type of value, whether it is `0`, a blank text string, etc. will return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

"Empty": only works on variables. Empty can mean different things for different variable types
(check manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

"isset": checks if the variable exists and checks for a true NULL or false value.
Can be unset by calling "unset". Once again, check the manual.

Use of either one depends of the variable type you are using.

I would say, it's safer to check for both, because you are checking first of all if the variable exists, and if it isn't really NULL or empty.

Comment: @szahn "safer to check for both", - you as programmer can check everything you want for the safety. But if your code is redundant then you can be redundant as programmer.

Answer (score -1):

if we use same page to add/edit via submit button like below

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?echo $_GET['edit_id'];?>" name="edit_id">
```

then we should not use

```
isset($_POST['edit_id'])
```

bcoz `edit_id` is set all the time whether it is add or edit page , instead  we should use  check below condition

```
!empty($_POST['edit_id'])
```