# Checking if a array is empty or not set in php?

Tags: php

I'm currently using:

```
if (isset($get['when']) && !strtotime($get['when']) && strtotime($get['when']) < time())
```

But i would also like it to include a way to check if `$get['when'] is empty('')`. How do I do this in the best manner?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($get['when']) && !empty($_GET['when']) && !strtotime($get['when']) && strtotime($get['when']) < time())
```

Use the [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function straight after you check that $_GET['when'] is set.

Comment: empty performs several checks, 1 being if the variable is set, and another being the variable length, there is no need for the isset, please see the manual

Answer (score 1):

`empty( $get['when'] )` will return `true` if `$get['when']` is an empty string. See [the manual's entry on `empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($get['when']) && !empty($get['when']) ...
```

Comment: `empty` performs several checks, 1 being if the variable is set, and another being the variable length, there is no need for the isset, please see the manual.

Comment: Ahh, every day *is* a school day! Thanks for pointing it out.