# Maintain checkbox value with dynamically created checkboxes and array

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, while-loop

I am trying to get my checkbox value to save on my dynamic created input, and I am failing miserably. Yes I've read a dozen or more tutorials online, but I cant find one that caters to a dynamic checkbox list... Please set me strait!!

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="checkboxForm">
<?php
$checkbox[] = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$checked = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? " checked" : "";

echo "<input name=\"checkbox[]\" type='checkbox' value='" . $row['first_name'] . "'     $checked /> ";
echo $row['first_name'];
echo "<hr />";
//print_r( $_POST['checkbox']);
}

if(isset($_POST['checkbox']) && !empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
 foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox){
echo $checkbox . "<br />";
} }
?>
```

Comment: can you show your generated html before posting??

Comment: For the record, `isset($_POST['checkbox']) && !empty($_POST['checkbox'])` is an anti-pattern that shouldn't exist in anyone's code for any reason.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HERE you go!!

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="checkboxForm">
<?php

    $chvalues = array();

    if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $ch => $value)
        {
            $chvalues[] = $value;
        }
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        if(in_array($row['first_name'], $chvalues))
        {
            echo "<input name=\"checkbox[]\" type='checkbox' value='" . $row['first_name'] . "' checked='checked'/> ";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<input name=\"checkbox[]\" type='checkbox' value='" . $row['first_name'] . "'/> ";
        }           
        echo $row['first_name'];
        echo "<hr />";      

    }

    if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox => $val){
            echo $checkbox .':'.$val."<br />";
    } 
?>
</form>
```

Comment: I see what you are doing, but part of the problem is the value needs to be retained as the first_name value. I can't use counter numbers.

Comment: @OldWest, well the idea is pretty much the same, could you post your generated html code?? perhaps we can get some clue from there?

Comment: <form action="/php/checkboxes_save_value.php" method="post" name="checkboxForm">

Array
(
    [0] => Mike
    [1] => Alycia
)
<input name="checkbox[]" type='checkbox' value='Mike'  /> Mike<hr />Array
(
    [0] => Mike
    [1] => Alycia
)
<input name="checkbox[]" type='checkbox' value='Alycia'  /> Alycia<hr />Mike<br />Alycia<br /><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Checkbox Data &gt;&gt;" /> Im doing a print_r for the results.

</form>

Comment: I can't believe this! This is not even working! foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox){
   // echo $checkbox . "<br />";
 $checked = $checkbox != "" ? " checked" : "";
} 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<input name=\"checkbox[]\" type='checkbox' value='" . $row['first_name'] . "' $checked /> ";
 echo $row['first_name'];
 echo "<hr />";
 //print_r( $_POST['checkbox']);
} both checkboxes are checked every time I submit IF only one checkbox is selected???

Comment: #experimentX, that did the trick. There was a misplaced bracket and some other minor items I had to adjust, but this solved the issue as far as I can tell. Thanks for the persistence.. My mind was pretty much melted.

Comment: @OldWest sure glad to help you .. i couldn't test because I didn't have the database.

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily verbose.  You only need to conditionally print `checked='checked'` not the full html markup.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$checked = isset($_POST['checkbox']) && in_array($row['first_name'], $_POST['checkbox']) ? " checked" : "";
```

Comment: Gaurav, I will try this in the morning. I like this approach as well it's much less code than I had originally.

Comment: While compact, this one-line answer is missing its educational explanation.