# Better way of writing this

Tags: php, coding-style

```
if (isset($row['product_limit'])){
    if ($row['product_limit'] != 0){
        echo $row['product_limit'];
    } else {
        echo $text_infinite;    
    }
} else {
    echo $text_infinite;
}
```

Is there a better way of writing this???

**EDIT:**

though I used the @Radu code but here is the version i used

```
echo (isset($row['product_limit']) 
&& $row['product_limit'] != 0) ? $row['product_limit'] : 'unlimited' ;
```

Not expected this many methods :) Thanks All

Comment: Wow, you really got some good results here.

Comment: the ternary operator is good if the code is short, otherwise it will become hard to read... If you prefer using 2 conditions (`isset` and `!= 0`) instead of one (`empty`), then you should consider using `if`/`else` instead of `?:`.

Comment: Also take a look at this question to find out about the difference between `empty()` and `isset()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this?

```
echo empty($row['product_limit']) ? $text_infinite : $row['product_limit'];
```

Take a look at the documentation for [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) and [the ternary conditional operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($row['product_limit']) && $row['product_limit'] != 0){
     echo $row['product_limit'];
} else {
    echo $text_infinite;    
}
```

Comment: @sterefrog why what is wrong with empty() ???

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($row['product_limit'])){
    echo $row['product_limit'];
} else {
    echo $text_infinite;    
}
```

As php.net says, the following things are considered to be empty:

- "" *(an empty string)*
- 0 *(0 as an integer)*

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try some EXME method.

```
    if (isset($row['product_limit']))
    {
        $msg = $row['product_limit'];
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "";
    }
```

Then you just need to output the code somewhere else by calling the echo of the $msg variable.