# Which is more reliable gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) or $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']

Tags: php

I have to get the remote url hostname from the `server` `script`, which one of the following is more reliable:

`gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` or `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with reliability. Both variables are just not the same although they may contain the same value under certain circumstances. Let me explain:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

will in all cases contain the IP address of the remote host, where

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']
```

will contain the DNS hostname, if DNS resolution is enabled (if the `HostnameLookups` Apache directive is set to `On`, thanks @Pekka). If it is disabled, then `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` will contain the IP address, and this is what you might have observed.

Your code should look like:

```
$host = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
// if both are the same, HostnameLookups seems to be disabled.
if($host === $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    // get the host name per dns call
    $host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
}
```

Note: If you can control the apache directive, I would advice you to turn it off for performance reasons and get the host name - only if you need it - using `gethostbyaddr()`

Comment: thanks for the reply. this way it does the lookup only if neccessary.

Comment: you are welcome. :) yes it grabs the host name only if required. Also you should check the note that I've added.

Answer (score 8):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` will only be set if the `HostnameLookups` Apache directive is set to `On`.

You could check for `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` first, and if it's not set, do a hostname lookup.

Both are likely to be equally reliable, as they will use the same lookup mechanism internally. For the general reliability of this information, see [Reliability of PHP'S $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715168/reliability-of-phps-serverremote-addr?rq=1)

Be aware that hostname lookups can be *very* slow. Don't do them unless you have a really good reason.