# Getting confused with empty, isset, !empty, !isset

Tags: php

I have the following which doesn't work properly as `$_GET['category']` can also equal 0.

```
if ( empty( $_GET['category'] ) ){
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

How do I re-write this if statement to do 3 different things

1. Do something if `$_GET['category']` does not exist at all
2. Do something if `$_GET['category'] == 0`
3. Do something if `$_GET['category'] ==` something other than "does not exist" and 0.

I've tried different combinations of `empty()`, `!empty()`, `isset()`, `!isset()` but I'm not getting the results I'm after.  I'm probably doing the wrong combinations...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why check both isset() and !empty()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)

Comment: Your requirements seem to conflict: point 3 is the counterpart of point 1 and 2. Therefor point 1, 2 and 3 combined will match all cases. Did you mean point 3 should `do something else` by any chance?

Comment: `===` also exists to. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really hard to do: `isset` is the method you need.

```
if (!isset($_GET['category'])) {
    // category isn't set
} elseif ($_GET['category'] === '0') {
    // category is set to 0
} else {
    // category is set to something other than 0
}
```

Note that I have compared for exact equality to the string `'0'`, because `GET` and `POST` variables are always strings (or occasionally arrays) and never numbers when PHP first receives them.

Comment: Disagree with "always strings". Personally more often than not seen sanitizing in combination with type casting even before validation starts, so that $_GET/$_POST contains `int`, `float`, etc.

Comment: @JürgenThelen That's quite unlikely given that we haven't even established that they exist yet...

Comment: in this specific case, yes. I'm just disagreeing with trivializing to "GET and POST variables are always strings" for each and every case.

Comment: @JürgenThelen Fair enough: clarified.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($_GET['category']))
{
    1. Do something if $_GET['category'] does not exist at all
}
elseif ($_GET['category'] == 0)
{
    2. Do something if $_GET['category'] == 0
}
elseif (isset($_GET['category']) && ($_GET['category'] != 0)
{
    3. Do something if $_GET['category'] == something other than "does not exist" and 0.
}
```

My brackets might be slightly out somewhere but hopefully that should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`filter_input`-function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['category'])) { // if variable not specified
}
elseif ($_GET['category'] == 0) { // variable is specified and zero
}
else { // variable is specified and not zero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$bad_values = array(null, '', 'dirty word');

if(isset($_GET['xd']))
{
    if(in_array($_GET['xd'], $bad_values, true))
    {
        // bad, it was null, empty or something else you think is not ok 
    }
    else
    {
        // it's fine, now check whether you got the zero. do a string comparison 

        if($_GET['xd'] == '0')
        {
            // you got the zero, yell at the user
        }
        else
        {
            // you got something else, it might be fine, it might be spoofed. use referential integrity to enforce data integrity in your db
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // it wasn't even sent in the request, that falls under 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `name` attribute of the element that is doing `get` on the previous page is set, preferably to the same as its `id`.
Then:

```
$category='';
if ( !isset( $_GET['category'] ) ){
    //1
} else {
    $category=$_GET['category'];
    //3
  if($category==0){
    //2
   }
}
```