# What does the exclamation point mean in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
>   [Getting confused with empty, isset, !empty, !isset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647305/getting-confused-with-empty-isset-empty-isset)

In PHP what is the difference between:

```
if(!isset) 
if(isset)
```

Same with `if(!empty)` and `if(empty)`?

What does the "!" character mean?

Comment: `if( isset($test) === false )` and `if( !isset($test) )` are equivalent.

Comment: Suggestion: Read the docs on [empty](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [isset](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to get a sense for how they work, differences, etc.

Comment: @jprofitt: actually, the logical negation operator appears to be missing from that list. You could probably add this question as the reference on `!`.

Answer (score 20):

`!` is the logical negation or `NOT` operator. It reverses the sense of the logical test.

That is:

- `if(isset)` makes something happen if `isset` is logical `True`.
- `if(!isset)` makes something happen if `isset` is logical **`False`**.

More about operators (logical and other types) in the [PHP documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) Look up `!` there to cement your understanding of what it does. While you're there, also look up the other logical operators:

- `&&` logical AND
- `||` logical OR
- `xor` logical EXCLUSIVE-OR

Which are also commonly used in logic statements.

Answer (score 8):

The `!` character is the logical "not" operator. It inverts the boolean meaning of the expression.

If you have an expression that evaluates to `TRUE`, prefixing it with `!` causes it evaluate to `FALSE` and vice-versa.

```
$test = 'value';

var_dump(isset($test));  // TRUE
var_dump(!isset($test)); // FALSE
```

---

`isset()` returns `TRUE` if the given variable is defined in the current scope with a non-null value.

`empty()` returns `TRUE` if the given variable is *not* defined in the current scope, or if it is defined with a value that is considered "empty". These values are:

```
NULL    // NULL value
0       // Integer/float zero
''      // Empty string
'0'     // String '0'
FALSE   // Boolean FALSE
array() // empty array
```

Depending PHP version, an object with no properties may also be considered empty.

The upshot of this is that `isset()` and `empty()` *almost* compliment each other (they return the opposite results) but not quite, as `empty()` performs an additional check on the value of the variable, `isset()` simply checks whether it is defined.

Consider the following example:

```
var_dump(isset($test)); // FALSE
var_dump(empty($test)); // TRUE

$test = '';

var_dump(isset($test)); // TRUE
var_dump(empty($test)); // TRUE

$test = 'value';

var_dump(isset($test)); // TRUE
var_dump(empty($test)); // FALSE
```

Comment: String `'0'` evaluates to logical false in PHP? Ugh. :(

Comment: @Li-aungYip I know it seems illogical but it is useful. Because PHP is *very* loosely typed, it makes sense when you consider that one is often working with data from `$_POST` and friends, where all data is `(string)`. In this instance, it is useful to be able to pass integers as booleans, and in order for this to work without explicit casting, `'0'` must evaluate to `FALSE`. Where it gets confusing is the fact that casting a string to int usually results in `0`, yet casting as bool results in `TRUE`, so `(bool) $str != (bool) (int) $str`

Comment: It's a useful idiom because it's easy - but type coercion always makes me a bit queasy because of the potential bugs. A typical pattern for me is to test the emptiness of a string by asking `if(string)`. In PHP both the empty string `''` and the literal `'0'` would pass this test, so I'd have to unlearn that habit.

Comment: Thanks, the example made a lot of sense

Comment: At least [PHP isn't Javascript](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat). Wat. ([See explanations on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the))

Comment: @Li-aungYip You see I am a PHP native so I am already is the habit of `===`ing everything, and as result I never run into those interesting little ECMA oddities you pointed either - but I can see how it would be annoying for those coming from a strongly typed background.

Answer (score 3):

```
$var = 0;

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}

// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($var)) {
    echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
}
```

Edit:

here is a test case for you:

```
$p = false;
echo isset($p) ? '$p is setted : ' : '$p is not setted : ';
echo empty($p) ? '$p is empty' : '$p is not empty';
echo "<BR>";
```

$p is setted : $p is empty