# PHP Checking input with isset

Tags: php, forms, input

In order to check if an input field is empty or has any value, will the following both methods work in same way? Or is any of them better than other?

```
if ($options['url']) {
    ..
}
```

**Or**

```
if ( isset ($options['url']) &&  ($options['url']!="") ) {
    ..
}
```

Comment: if key does not exist in array, then a NOTICE will be thrown

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why check both isset() and !empty()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without checking with `isset()` you will get at least a notice message if `$options` is not an array or the index `url` does not exist. So `isset()` should be used.

You could also use

```
if (! empty($options['url'])) {
    ...
}
```

[Empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) checks for any false value (like an empty string, undefined, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Isset determine if a variable is not NULL and is set.

($options['url']) determine if a variable return true

Answer (score 1):

The code below only checks that the value, assuming the key exists, is true. A notice will be fired if the key doesn't exist.
    if ($options['url']) {
        ..
    }

`isset` will tell you if the key exists and the value is not null.

I'd use `empty` as it will return false if the key doesn't exist and it will also return false if the key does exist yet the value is empty.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The `$options['url']!=""`checks if variable is empty,

while `isset($options['url'])` checks if the variable has been **set** or is **not NULL**.

### Anyway, calling `isset()` always on variables or array keys that **may or may not exist** must be a rule.

or you'll get all those 'undefined' warnings...

Answer (score 1):

The following should be sufficient:

```
if (isset($options["url"]) && $options["url"]) {
   // ...
}
```

1. The [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is used to check if a specific key is present in the array (and to avoid the *undefined index* notice). It is a good programming practice. You can also use the [`array_key_exist()`](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function in this case but `isset` is usually faster.
2. When an expression such as `$options['url']` is used inside a boolean context; its truthiness is checked (see the [converting to boolean section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)). The [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function produces identical result for most expressions.