# only echo html if a $get condition is met

Tags: php, html

I am redirecting various messages from a header and echoing them onto a new page. How can I change this so that the html only appears if there is a message variable to echo. i.e., if one of the `$_GET` conditions are met? Thanks

```
$message="";

if(isset($_GET['pw']))
{
  $message = "first message";
}
else if(isset($_GET['em']))
{
  $message = "second message";
}
else if(isset($_GET['fn']))
{
  $message = "third message";
}
else if(isset($_GET['ln']))
{
  $message = "forth message";
}
    ?>
<html>
     <body>
         <table class='tab2'>
             <td class='td2'><?php echo $message; ?></td>
         </table>
     </body>
<html>
```

Comment: if `!empty($message) { output the html }`

Comment: what goes in the curly parentheses?

Comment: @user1531158 Your entire html block. Close the `?>` after the opening `{`, output the HTML, and reopen `<?php` for the closing `}`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   if($message)
   {
?>

   <html>
   ....

   </html>

<?php
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<?php
$message="";

if(isset($_GET['pw']) && !empty($_GET['pw']))
{
  $message = "first message";
}
else if(isset($_GET['em']) && !empty($_GET['em']))
{
  $message = "second message";
}
else if(isset($_GET['fn']) && !empty($_GET['fn']))
{
  $message = "third message";
}
else if(isset($_GET['ln']) && !empty($_GET['ln']))
{
  $message = "forth message";
}
echo $message;
?>
```

Demo: http://shaquin.tk/experiments/get-conditions.php

It checks to see if a `$_GET` variable is defined, and if it is not empty, sets `$message` to the appropriate message.

See [empty - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [isset - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

**EDIT:**

If you want to display multiple messages, use this code:

```
$message=array();
if(isset($_GET['pw']) && !empty($_GET['pw']))
{
  $message[] = "first message";
}
if(isset($_GET['em']) && !empty($_GET['em']))
{
  $message[] = "second message";
}
if(isset($_GET['fn']) && !empty($_GET['fn']))
{
  $message[] = "third message";
}
if(isset($_GET['ln']) && !empty($_GET['ln']))
{
  $message[] = "forth message";
}
echo implode("\n", $message);
```

Demo: http://shaquin.tk/experiments/get-conditions2.php

It initializes `$message` as an array, then adds to the array if a condition is met.

Before printing the message, it `implode`s it, using a newline character as 'glue'.

See [implode - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

For an HTML page, you would probably want to set the 'glue' as a `<br />` element, like this:

```
echo implode('<br />', $message);
```

(or if you are using HTML4):

```
echo implode('<br>', $message);
```

Comment: [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/2943403) and also https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#:~:text=The%20keyword%20elseif%20SHOULD%20be%20used%20instead%20of%20else%20if%20so%20that%20all%20control%20keywords%20look%20like%20single%20words.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php if (!empty($message)) { echo $message;}?>`

or

`<?php if (isset($message)) { echo $mssage;}?>`

or

`<?php if (isset($message) || $message !== "") { echo $message; } ?>`

or anything to do `if message exists then do this`

Comment: hi, thanks for the code, still having some trouble, maybe I am putting it in the wrong place, where exactly should it go?

Comment: So, the code you provided basically says, "if x is set, make message=messageX; if y is set, make message=messageY" The next step would be placed in your HTML where you typed your "echo $message" code. What you are looking to do, is only echo ANY message if ANY message is set. So the code you'll need is NOT merely "echo $message", but you need "if a message is set, THEN echo $message"

Comment: `!== ""` then `isset()` is the wrong order of checking.  If `$message` is not declared, then the first check will cause trouble because it would try to access an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if ($message != "") { ?> 
   All your HTML code (including echo $message) goes here 
<?php
} else { do nothing here }
?>
```

Comment: `$message !== ""` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone's answer has pretty much the same idea but, specifically, here is how you can do it:

```
$message="";

if(isset($_GET['pw']))
{
  $message = "first message";
}
else if(isset($_GET['em']))
{
  $message = "second message";
}
else if(isset($_GET['fn']))
{
  $message = "third message";
}
else if(isset($_GET['ln']))
{
  $message = "forth message";
}
?>
<?php if ($message) :?>
<html>
    <head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .tab2
        {
            width:400px; height:40px;
            position: absolute; right: 300px; top: 70px;
        }

        .td2
        {
            background-color:pink;
            color:blue;
            text-align:center;
        }
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>

         <table class='tab2'>
             <td class='td2'><?php echo $message; ?></td>
         </table>
     </body>
<html>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: that worked fantastically, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out here your a star :D

Comment: With this method, to use a bit less code, use `<?php if($message) { ?>` at the start of the HTML and `<?php } ?>` at the end.

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff Yes, I used to do that. However, I got told that `endif` is easier to spot when coding on a file where PHP is mixed with HTML (I now believe that too).

Comment: Well, I suppose it comes down to personal preference. :-) I use `}` because it fits in with the rest of the language, otherwise it seems like a strange mix between VB and C++...

Comment: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#:~:text=The%20keyword%20elseif%20SHOULD%20be%20used%20instead%20of%20else%20if%20so%20that%20all%20control%20keywords%20look%20like%20single%20words.