# If statement with condition isset and comparing not working together

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having a problems with making `if` statements:

```
<?php if (isset($detail) == 1) { ?>
    // code if detail variable exists and is equal to 1
<?php } else { ?>
    // code if detail variable doesn't exist or is not equal 1
<?php }?>
```

For some reason this condition doesn't work. How could I fix the `if` condition, so it will work?

Comment: What `details` value is producing an unexpected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset` is a boolean operator which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. You don't need to compare it to `1`.

```
if( isset($detail) )
```

As a side note, just because the variable is set, does not mean it's not empty. You may want to just check that it's not empty:

```
if( !empty($detail) )
```

Comment: aha so this could be the problem, becasue I am sending something like this `$this->data['detail'] = 0;` or `$this->data['detail'] = 1;`

Comment: So, should I use rather empty too? Could it be done even simpler? I mean any function in php for this "double check"?

Comment: if it doesn't exist I will do my helper, but it would be neat if it already exists in php

Comment: @Derfder You can just use `empty`. [Read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty).

Comment: So e.g. if the variable $detail is not sent at all to the view, no php error will pop up? Is using empty enough to prevent nasty php errors caused by not sending variable to the view?

Comment: `empty` will return `true` if the value is `''`, `0.0`, `'0'`, `0`, `FALSE`, `array()`. Do you want that?

Comment: is this better than `!empty`?: `if(isset($detail) && $detail === TRUE)`