# array_push only returns the last element that has been pushed into the new array?

Tags: php

So I'm trying to create an array inside a loop so that I can use its elements elsewhere in the code ...

And so when I try to var_dump the array to see if all the expected elements have been added into the array , I only see the last element of the array inside the new array .. Could anyone  explain me why ... Below is the relevant part of the code

```
$select  = "SELECT * FROM DEVICES";
$result = mysql_query($select);
$result_count = mysql_num_rows($result)

if($result_count > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        echo "<td> <a class='inline' href='/profiles.php?id=".$row['ID']."'><img src='".$row['Picture']."'width='50' height='50' class ='image' /></a> <br /> <br /> <div style='color: blue; font-weight:bold; font-size:15px;'> By ".$row['Name']." </td>";
        $user_array = array();
        if(array_key_exists("Device",$row)){
            array_push ($user_array,$row["Device"]);
        }    
    }
}
var_dump($user_array);  // only returns the last element inserted into $user_array.
```

Comment: Trouble shooting these issues are most comfortable by using a remote debugger, for example xdebug in PHP: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: X-Ref same type of mistake: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17140454/367456

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are resetting the array every time the body of the while loop executes.

You have to initialize the array outside of the loop:

```
$user_array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<td> <a class='inline' href='/profiles.php?id=".$row['ID']."'><img src='".$row['Picture']."'width='50' height='50' class ='image' /></a> <br /> <br /> <div style='color: blue; font-weight:bold; font-size:15px;'> By ".$row['Name']." </td>";

    if(array_key_exists("Device",$row)) {
        array_push ($user_array,$row["Device"]);
    }    
}

var_dump($user_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, more simple.

```
$user_array = array();
if (isset($row["Device"]) && !empty($row["Device"])) {
  $user_array[] = $row["Device"];
}
```

and you have clean array with data.

```
print_r($user_array);
```

Comment: Using [`isset() && !empty()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403) is an antipattern that should not be in anyone's code for any reason.