# Writing PHP Array Into Single Value

Tags: php, arrays

I am implementing `jqGrid` with multiple search. But I have a trouble to get an array into single value. This is my code:

```
//I get this from url giving by jqGrid

$json_data = '{"groupOp":"OR","rules":[{"field":"first_name","op":"eq","data":"ale"},{"field":"last_name","op":"ne","data":"ger"},{"field":"first_name","op":"cn","data":"ros"}]}';

$myArray = json_decode($json_data);

$theArray = $myArray->rules;


foreach($theArray as $tArr) 
{
    //echoing field
    $thisWhere = $tArr->field. " ";

    //get operation 
    if($tArr->op == 'eq') {
        $thisWhere .= '= '; //equal
        $thisWhere .= '"'.$tArr->data.'" '.$myArray->groupOp.' ';
    } 
    else if ($tArr->op == 'ne') {
        $thisWhere .= '<> '; //not equal
        $thisWhere .= $tArr->data.' '.$myArray->groupOp.' ';
    }
    else if ($tArr->op == 'lt') {
        $thisWhere .= '< '; //less
        $thisWhere .= $tArr->data.' '.$myArray->groupOp.' ';
    }
    else if ($tArr->op == 'le') {
        $thisWhere .= '<= '; //less equal
        $thisWhere .= $tArr->data.' '.$myArray->groupOp.' ';
    }
    else if ($tArr->op == 'gt') {
        $thisWhere .= '> '; //greater than
        $thisWhere .= $tArr->data.' '.$myArray->groupOp.' ';
    }

    echo $thisWhere; //echo inside foreach
    //return ===> first_name = "ale" OR last_name <> "ger" OR first_name < 20 OR
}

//echo $thisWhere; //return ===> first_name < 20 OR
```

if echoing inside `foreach`, return;
`first_name = "ale" OR last_name <> "ger" OR first_name < 20 OR`

if echoing outside `foreach`, return; `first_name < 20 OR`

All I want is echoing or get `$thisWhere` variable outside `foreach` loop. So, I can do next step.

Comment: Take a look at the first line inside your loop.  `$thisWhere = (some whole other value that doesn't include the results from the previous iteration);`  :P

Comment: HAHA... Fool me... fool me... I just forgot to write $thisWhere .= $tArr->field;
THANK YOU VERY MUCH...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting `$thisWhere` each time through the loop.  It'll only ever have the results from the last iteration.  You'd need to append to it instead.  (I'd suggest setting it to `''` before the loop as well, to avoid notices and some types of oddness.)

I usually prefer to group the conditions into an array, though...like so:

```
# by the way, there's not really a need for all the if/else junk.
# watch this.
$ops = array(
    'eq' => '=',  'lt' => '<',  'gt' => '>',
    'ne' => '<>', 'ge' => '>=', 'le' => '<=',
);

# stringify each condition
$conditions = array();
foreach ($theArray as $comp) {
    $conditions[] = "{$comp->field} {$ops[$comp->op]} {$comp->data}";
}

# now you can just glue them together at the end
$thisWhere = implode(" {$myArray->groupOp} ", $conditions);
```

Aside from being a lot simpler, it also ensures you only use the AND/OR to separate conditions.  If you do it in the loop, you have to jump through some hoops to avoid having that extra `OR` at the end.

Comment: :) My way is little tricky. And your way is very simple. Thank for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

use implode($theArray); method that converts your array in single string.
Hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you for answering. :) Implode doesn't work since I want something to do inside foreach loop.