# PHP Multidimensional array push values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can someone help me how to push values into multidimensional array?

here is my code:

`

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('10.10.10.10', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'pass');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'show l2circuit connections brief | display json');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out=ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
$units = json_decode(stream_get_contents($stream_out), true);
$ps_data=array();

for ($i=0; $i <= count($units["l2circuit-connection-information"][0]["l2circuit-neighbor"][0]["connection"])+1; $i++) {
    $dev_ip=$units["l2circuit-connection-information"][0]["l2circuit-neighbor"][$i]["neighbor-address"][0]["data"];
    #$ps_data[$i]=$dev_ip;
    for ($d=0; $d < count($units["l2circuit-connection-information"][0]["l2circuit-neighbor"][$i]["connection"]); $d++) {
        $ps_int = explode(".", $units["l2circuit-connection-information"][0]["l2circuit-neighbor"][$i]["connection"][$d]["connection-id"][0]["data"]);
        $ps_data[$dev_ip] = array($d => $ps_int[0]);
        

    }
}
echo "<pre>";

print_r($ps_data)
```

`

here is output:
`

```
Array
(
    [10.255.255.140] => Array
        (
            [4] => ps203
        )

    [10.255.255.171] => Array
        (
            [6] => ps44
        )

    [10.255.255.172] => Array
        (
            [6] => ps205
        )

    [10.255.255.173] => Array
        (
            [7] => ps25
        )

    [10.255.255.174] => Array
        (
            [8] => ps51
        )

    [10.255.255.178] => Array
        (
            [4] => ps37
        )

    [10.255.255.193] => Array
        (
            [8] => ps33
        )

)
```

`

In this case each $dev_ip have several interfaces and I want to push them to array but it added only last interface with corresponding index

Comment: Related: [array_push only returns the last element that has been pushed into the new array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15802459/2943403) and [Writing PHP Array Into Single Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17140454/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your big problem is

```
$ps_data[$dev_ip] = array($d => $ps_int[0]);
```

This overwrites any previous contents of the array with a new array with 1 element.

Instead, you should add the new item to the array...

```
$ps_data[$dev_ip][$d] = $ps_int[0];
```