# Isset expression error

Tags: php, isset

I have basically coded a code which populates a list of categories from my database then you are able to select which to delete.

I have the issue with the delete code which does not seem to work due to the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in F:\xamppnew\htdocs\650032\admin\delete.php on line 6
```

The line causing this is:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_id'] && !empty($_POST['delete_id']))) {
```

deletecategory.php

```
    <h3>
     Delete Category
    </h3>

    <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category"); ?>

<table>
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
  <tr id="<?php echo $row['category_id']; ?>">
    <td><?php echo $row['category_Name']; ?></td>
    <td>
      <button class="del_btn" rel="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.del_btn').click(function(){
       var del_id = $(this).attr('rel');
       $.post('delete.php', {delete_id:del_id}, function(data) {
          if(data == 'true') {
            $('#'+del_id).remove();
          } else {
            alert('Could not delete!');
          }
       });
    });
  });
</script>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['delete_id'] && !empty($_POST['delete_id']))) {
      $delete_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delete_id']);
      $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM category WHERE `id`=".$delete_id);
      if($result !== false) {
        echo 'true';
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. [`mysql_real_escape_string` does only work if the value is used in a MySQL string literal.](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/35718/539)

Comment: There is no need to use `isset()` and `!empty()` at the same time. `empty` also works if the input is not defined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You missed this `)`:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_id']) && !empty($_POST['delete_id']))
                            ^---
```

Answer (score 7):

Others have shown the issue of the missing `)` in the expression, but `empty()` will check `isset()` so that is redundant.  Just check `empty()`:

```
if(!empty($_POST['delete_id'])) {
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that this

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_id'] && !empty($_POST['delete_id'])))
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_id']) && !empty($_POST['delete_id']))
```