# PHP - Check GET Variables Exist And Not Empty

Tags: php

I want to check the GET variables are not empty, I tried ways but they didn't work.

So I had the code like this:

```
$u = isset($_GET["u"]);
$p = isset($_GET["p"]);
if ($u !== "" && $p !== "") {
    //something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

The I checked the code by sending `create.php?u=&p=`, but the code didn't work. It kept running the `//do something` part. The I tried:

```
echo $u;
echo $p;
```

It returned `1` and `1`. Then I changed it to:

```
if ($u !== 1 && $p !== 1 && $u !== "" && $p !== "") {
    //something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

But it continued to run `//do something`.

Please help.

Comment: isset returns a bool so it will never `== ""`

Comment: $u returns true or false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use [empty](https://www.php.net/empty) which is a PHP function. It will automatically check if it exists and whether there is any data in it:

```
if(empty($var))
{
    // This variable is either not set or has nothing in it.
}
```

In your case, as you want to check AGAINST it being empty you can use:

```
if (!empty($u) && !empty($p))
{
    // You can continue...
}
```

Edit: Additionally the [comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `!==` will check for not equal to AND of the same type. While in this case GET/POST data are strings, so the use is correct (comparing to an empty string), be careful when using this. The normal PHP comparison for not equal to is `!=`.

Additional Edit: Actually, (amusingly) it is. Had you used a `!=` to do the comparison, it would have worked. As the `==` and `!=` operators perform a loose comparison, `false == ""` returns true - hence your if statement code of `($u != "" && $p != "")` would have worked the way you expected.

```
<?php 
$var1=false;
$var2="";
$var3=0;

echo ($var1!=$var2)? "Not Equal" : "Equal";
echo ($var1!==$var2)? "Not Equal" : "Equal";

echo ($var1!=$var3)? "Not Equal" : "Equal";
echo ($var1!==$var3)? "Not Equal" : "Equal";

print_r($var1);
print_r($var2);
?>

// Output: Equal
// Output: Not Equal

// Output: Equal
// Output: Not Equal
```

Final edit: Change your condition in your if statement to:

```
if ($u != "" && $p != "")
```

It will work as you expected, it won't be the best way of doing it (nor the shortest) but it *will* work the way you intended.

Really the Final Edit:

Consider the following:

```
$u = isset($_GET["u"]); // Assuming GET is set, $u == TRUE
$p = isset($_GET["p"]); // Assuming GET is not set, $p == FALSE
```

Strict Comparisons:

```
if ($u !== "") 
// (TRUE !== "" - is not met. Strict Comparison used - As expected)

if ($p !== "")
// (FALSE !== "" - is not met. Strict Comparison used - Not as expected)
```

While the Loose Comparisons:

```
if ($u != "") 
// (TRUE != "" - is not met. Loose Comparison used - As expected)

if ($p != "")
// (FALSE != "" - is met. Loose Comparison used)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, +1, but ;( i can't accept your answer because the error was not because of the `!==`. how about if you had it fixed, i will accept your answer? ;)

Comment: @DanielCheung No thank you, I love to get into the nitty-gritty of code, so spending a few moments to really think about how things work (while sipping a nice glass of red) was the perfect way to relax this evening :)

Comment: actually, my problem was `$u = isset($_GET["u"]);`

Comment: @DanielCheung PHP loose comparisons allow the comparison of boolean types to many things quite well. Have a read of the (really final lol) addition to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need `!empty()`

```
if (!empty($_GET["p"]) && !empty($_GET["u"])) {
    //something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

*[Helpful Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)*

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($u !== 1 && $p !== 1 && $u !== "" && $p !== "")
```

1. why are you using "!==" and not "!=".
2. to always simplify your problem solve the logic on paper once  using the runtime $u and $p value.

To check if `$_GET` value is blank or not you can use 2 methods.

1. since `$_GET` is an array you can use `if(count($_GET))` if you have only u and p to check or check all incoming $_GET parameters.
2. empty function @Fluffeh referred to.
3. `if($_GET['u']!=""&&$_GET['p']!="")`

Hope it helps thx

Answer (score 0):

In you code you should correctly check the variable existence like

```
if ($u != NULL && $p != NULL && $u != 0 && $p != 0) {
    //something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow! I was so dumb... `isset` returns a boolean. I fixed my problem now. Thank you for answering anyway :)

This fixes:

```
$u = $_GET["u"];
$p = $_GET["p"];
```

Comment: Please do read my answer though, it is the better way of doing it :)