# multiple html href to php page

Tags: php, html

I have an html page

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div><a href="MySubmissionView.php">Number of Applications:</a></div>
            <div><a href="MySubmissionView.php">Submitted Applications:</a></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and i have a php page 'MySubmissionView.php' for some process.
in my php page how i know which link is i have clicked.?thanks in advance

Comment: Add a query string. e.g. MySubmissionView.php?page=number and MySubmissionView.php?page=submitted

Comment: @HenriHietala you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div><a href="MySubmissionView.php?id=xx1">Number of Applications:</a></div>
<div><a href="MySubmissionView.php?id=xx2">Submitted Applications:</a></div>
```

Php page:

```
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    echo '<p>The id is: '.$_GET['id'].'</p>';
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Redundant, `empty()` already check if the var is set. [See detailed answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)

Answer (score 2):

Add a query string to your hrefs. e.g. MySubmissionView.php?page=number and MySubmissionView.php?page=submitted. You can access the query string from your php with `$_GET('paramname')`. Here's an example:

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div><a href="MySubmissionView.php?page=number">Number of Applications:</a></div>
            <div><a href="MySubmissionView.php?page=submitted">Submitted Applications:</a></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
  if($_GET['page'] == 'number') {
    // process page number here
  } elseif($_GET['page'] == 'submitted') {
    // process page submitted here
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the previus comment, and as personal opinion, I would change that `isset()` to `!empty()`

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div><a href="MySubmissionView.php?click=1">Number of Applications:</a></div>
            <div><a href="MySubmissionView.php?click=2">Submitted Applications:</a></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

MySubmissionView.php:

```
if($_GET['click'] == 1){
   echo "first a clicedk";
}else{
    echo "second a clicedk";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div><a href="MySubmissionView.php?go=1">Number of Applications:</a></div>
        <div><a href="MySubmissionView.php?go=2">Submitted Applications:</a></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Above is your HTML And Your PHP of MySubmissionView.php should look like below.

```
<?php
     $go = "";
       if(isset($_GET)){
            if(isset($_GET['go'])){
                $go = $_GET['go'];
            }else{
                // do something if '$_GET['go']' is not set
            }
      }else{
        // Do something if u don't get a $_GET Request
      }

    echo 'Clicked Page'.$go;
?>
```

--

```
 if(isset($_GET))
```

Will check the page gets either GET / Post Request. [Read about Get / Post Methods](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php)