# Can 'if X, then echo X' be shortened in PHP?

Tags: php

The shortest way to echo out stuff in views in PHP - when not using template engines - is, afaik, this one:

```
<?php if (!empty($x)) echo $x; ?>
```

For a deeper explanaition why using `!empty` is a good choice please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty).

**Is it possible to write this without writing the variable name twice (like in other languages), something like**

```
!echo $x;
```

or

```
echo? $x;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built in? No.

However - you could write your own wrapper function to do it:

```
$x = 'foobar';
myecho($x); // foobar

function myecho($x) {
    echo !empty($x) ? $x : '';
}
```

This fits the bill of "only writing the variable once", but doesn't give you as much flexibility as the echo command does because this is a function that is using echo, so you can't do something like: `myecho($x . ', '. $y)` (the argument is now always defined and not empty once it hits `myecho()`)

Comment: Do not forget to check if `myecho` function exists with [function_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to prevent fatal error.

Comment: @VitalyChirkov so you are writing `<?php if(class_exists('foo')) { return; }; class foo {}`? :D

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Nope, I use namespaces :P

Comment: @VitalyChirkov i wanted to say, if i see a fatal error it is better for debugging then call a function that is not the one i think it is ;)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt yep, agree. I take it back.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo @$x;
```

**It's not exactly the right way to do it, but** it is shorter.
it reduces the need to check if $x exists since @ silences the error thrown when $x == null;

edit

```
echo empty($x) ? "" : $x;
```

is a shorter way, which is not really that much shorter nor does it solve your problem.

guess the other answers offer a better solution by addressing to make a short function for it.

Comment: Using `@` is officially very bad syntax as it surpresses notices (I think the PSR guys have defined that). Not an option in modern development anymore!

Comment: I quote: "It's not exactly the right way to do it, but...".

Comment: My +1 is for your first example. Your second doesn't solve the "only write the variable once" part though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write a function:

```
function echoIfNotEmpty($val) {
   if (!empty($val)) {
       echo $val;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
echoIfNotEmpty($x);
```

Sure you can shorten the function name.

---

If you don't know, if the var is intialized you can also do:

```
function echoIfNotEmpty(&$val = null) {
   if (!empty($val)) {
       echo $val;
   }
}
```

Most times we want do prefix and append something

```
function echoIfNotEmpty(&$val = null, $prefix = '', $suffix = '') {
   if (!empty($val)) {
       echo $prefix . $val . $suffix;
   }
}

echoIfNotEmpty($x, '<strong>', '</strong>');
```

Comment: Good one! I've not even thought about this possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Easy approach would be to define an helper function so:

```
function mEcho($someVariable) {
  if(!empty($someVariable) echo $someVariable;
}
```

I'm not sure though if that's what you intended.