# isset() and NOT operator

Tags: php

I know about questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty). There are lots of them with great answers.

I know this was "fixed" in PHP `5.5.x`, but I'm unfortunately I'm using `5.3.x`.

```
$iHatePHP = $node->get($key);
if (isset($node->get($key)) ...
```

The error I get:

`Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in ...`

I know the "fix" is to put the result of `get()` into a variable and call `isset()` on that. However, in order to save writing that thousands of times in my code, is it equivalent or am I missing some cases?

```
$iHatePHP = $node->get($key);
if (!($node->get($key)) ...
```

**Edit:** I control `get()`. So I can make it return anything I like, such as `NULL`, `FALSE` or `""`

Comment: try`if (!isset($node->get($key)) `

Comment: Is your question about the not operator or about calling isset on function return values?

Comment: @Boann I should have written if (!isset($node->get($key)). Sorry. So, yes, my question is about calling isset() on function return values.

Answer (score 2):

The [`isset()` pseudo-function](http://php.net/isset) checks not for a variable that would cast to `false`, but for one which is `null`. Additionally, it checks for a variable or array key's *existence*; a non-existent variable would be `null` anyway, but would also issue a Notice, in case you had mistyped the name or similar.

When you are testing the result of a function or method call, you know that there is *some* return value (a function with no `return` statement, or a plain `return;` with no value, is returning `null`), so the extra case of "no such variable" is impossible. The easiest way to test the value is therefore [`is_null`](http://php.net/is_null):

```
if ( is_null($node->get($key)) ) ...
```

If `$node->get($key)` returns `false`, `0`, or `''`, the `!` version would enter the `if` statement due to [the rules on converting other types to boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

The similar [`empty()` construct](http://php.net/empty) *does* evaluate as though you had applied a `!` operator, but preserves the special behaviour for non-existent variables - `empty($foo)` is effectively the same as `! isset($foo) || ! (bool)$foo`.