# php validation: is isset() necessary together with !empty()

Tags: php, validation, isset

If I want to check if element(e.g. $_POST['name']) exists I do that:

A.) `if(isset($_POST['name']))`

If I want to see if element exists and is not empty, I  do B.) or is it C.) enough?

B.) `if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']))`

C.) `if(!empty($_POST['name']))`

I've tried and C.) worked fine, but reputable school always used B.) approach and I asked my instructor there and she said I should use B.) approach, although I am not clear why and I decided to ask here to be sure and not to do an overkill if it is not necessary. [They didn't explain me why.]
Can You give me some examples why I should use B.) over C.)?

Thanks and have a great and good day, Gregor Leskovšek from Slovenia

Comment: C only works fine on servers set to not throw an error when encountering an index that doesn't exist. Move that code to a different server, and it might break.

Comment: `isset` checks for variable presence, and `empty` for *truthiness* (empty strings and zeroed strings are considered falsy). So depends on what you want to accomplish. An isset/strlen combo is actually what most use cases call for.

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty

Comment: This guide will learn you "everything" about isset and empty: http://kunststube.net/isset/

Comment: I always recursively `trim()` the POST array with a custom `trim_r($_POST)` function and then use `if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] !== '')`

Comment: user please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Comment: People are interested in getting answers but not interested in marking the answers. really frustrating. deleting my answers.

Comment: I am sorry I did not get this one. I do not have reputation to vote. And what will the answer be in PHP 7 ?? ternary shortest and safest?