# php handling multiple API calls

Tags: php

trying to find the best solution. I have a form which takes two inputs: input1 and input2.  I use javascript to validate these fields - as long as one of them is filled in correctly that is ok.

At the moment, I have the following PHP (removed includes)

```
if (isset($_POST["input1"]) && !empty($_POST["input1"])){
    $input1 = $_POST["input1"];
    $connection = new APIConnection1();
    $response = $connection->obtainResponse($input1);
}

if (isset($_POST["input2"]) && !empty($_POST["input2"])){
    $input2 = $_POST["input2"];
    $connection = new APIConnection2();
    $response = $connection->obtainResponse($input2);
}
```

So if input1 has data - APIConnection1 is called.
If input2 has data - APIConnection2 is called.
If both of them have valid data - both APIs are called. So each input has its own API (different).

Here is my problem.  I now have a third API, lets call it APIConnection3.  If response returned for input1 is true, I need to send input1 to APIConnection3.  Same applies with input2.

Problem is, I cant really make these calls within the above if statements because it will make separate calls to APIConnection3.  So I need to somehow perform the above if statements, and then get the data as a whole to send to APIConnection3.

So, if both input1 and input2 return true, I want to make one call which would be

```
APIConnection3($input1, $input2);
```

If only one of them returns true, then it should be something like

```
APIConnection3($input1);
```

So how would I handle doing this?

Thanks

Comment: [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a PHP function "call_user_func_array()" which accepts controller, method and parameters.

So you could do something like this:

```
$params = array();

if (isset($_POST["input1"]) && !empty($_POST["input1"])) {
    $input1 = $_POST["input1"];
    $connection = new APIConnection1();
    $response1 = $connection->obtainResponse($input1);
    array_push($params, $response1);
}
if (isset($_POST["input2"]) && !empty($_POST["input2"])) {
    $input2 = $_POST["input2"];
    $connection = new APIConnection2();
    $response2 = $connection->obtainResponse($input2);
    array_push($params, $response2);
}

$controller = new APIConnection3();
$response = call_user_func_array(array($controller, "obtainResponse"), $params);
```

Comment: Thats really helpful, works fantastically.  One strange thing though.  In my obtainResponse function I try to loop the params array.  Its complaining that its an  Invalid argument supplied for foreach().  Am I missing something here?

Comment: The parameters are passed as individual variables, so your function should expect 0 to 2 parameters coming. so you could declare the method like so: obtainResponse($response1 = null, $response2 = null). I edited the answer so the params array should contain response1 and/or response2.

Answer (score 2):

As you add more inputs , your code will be more difficult to extend, thats when design patterns become handy.

For example the Factory Method:

```
$inputs = new array();

if (isset($_POST["input1"]) && !empty($_POST["input1"])){
    $input1 = $_POST["input1"];
    $connection = new APIConnection1();
    $response = $connection->obtainResponse($input1);
    $inputs[0] = $input1;
}

if (isset($_POST["input2"]) && !empty($_POST["input2"])){
    $input2 = $_POST["input2"];
    $connection = new APIConnection2();
    $response = $connection->obtainResponse($input2);
    $inputs[1] = $input2;
}

//Call for each input
$connection = new APIConnection3();
foreach ($inputs as $input)
{   
    $response = $connection->obtainResponse($input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's dozens of ways you can do that. Here is one (i omitted most code, since your question is more about the logic):

```
if(CASE_01 || CASE_02) {
    if(CASE_01 && CASE_02) {
        //Both Inputs...
    }
    else if(CASE_01) {
        //Only Input 1...
    }
    else {
        //only input 2...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using CURL. Please check these CURL functions
curl_multi_add_handle(),curl_multi_exec() and curl_multi_getcontent()

Create single function like multithread() and pass input1 and input2 value to this function , create loop of request [ your case will be 2] and execute using curl_multi_getcontent you will get result for both APIS like

```
    $master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
        $curl_arr[$i]       = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $apiturl);
            curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);


 }
do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
    usleep(10000);
} while($running > 0);


for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{

    $results[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
}
 /* check result*/
 print_r($results);
```