# PHP multiply conditions

Tags: php, session, conditional-statements

I thought, constructions like `if(){}-else{}` are so common, that I would never have problems with this. 
But...with next code my brain is blowing up. Need any advice.
Subject is:

```
//print_r($_SESSION);
/*array(    
[filterSub] => Array
        (
            [app] => vedushchiye
            [workin] => Array
                (
                    [0] => vecherinka
                )
        )
)*/
$catCur = 'vedushchiye'; //for example
if (!empty($_SESSION['filterSub']) && isset($_SESSION['filterSub']['app']) && !empty($_SESSION['filterSub']['app']) && $_SESSION['filterSub']['app'] != $catCur && $catCur != 'performers'){
                $_SESSION['filterSub']['workin'] = array();
                echo ' stage 2 ok ';
            }
```

So, I expected that the condition will not run.

And it really did not run, but this part `$_SESSION['filterSub']['workin'] = array();` ran and `echo ' stage 2 ok ';` wasn't.

How is it possible?

Comment: How are you determining whether something "did run" or "did not run"?

Comment: Are you intending on those comments being in there?

Comment: Have you used error reporting to determine the break points of the code? IE `ini_set('display_errors',1);` `ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);` `error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @David if this condition ran, i should see "stage 2 ok", and I don't see it. But workin in session became empty array

Comment: @Zak yes, used ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(-1); . Nothing

Comment: You may have some other code that's setting the session variable.

Comment: How exactly are you checking that "workin in session became empty array"? Can you post the results of `print_r($_SESSION)` immediately after your `if` statement completes?

Comment: @Barmar no, I checked everywhere.

Comment: (As a side note, you could simplify that conditional, bearing in mind that [a combined `isset()` and `!empty()` are redundant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)).

Comment: Working as expected here: https://3v4l.org/mCW55 - your best chance is probably to set up a debugger like e.g. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html