# How to make FILTER section in e commerce website

Tags: php, html, web

i want to make an e commerce website and i want to know how to make filter section where people can omit or select a given variety of product.
Something like the one in the image.

[image]

Any kind of help will be of great use.
Thank you.

Comment: Well... you write all the HTML, CSS, PHP and, presumable, SQL code needed to filter products. That's quite a bit of code. Better get started. If you have a specific question along the way, ask that **specific question**.

Answer (score -1):

well you can use php like this i am just giving an example here let's say i have a i have to apply filter first to country than to region
so your form will go like this

```
<form action="this.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="country">
<input type="text" name="region">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and your php code will go like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['country'] && !empty($_POST['country']) && isset($_POST['region'] && !empty($_POST['region']))
{
$country=$_POST['country'];
$region=$_POST['region'];
$connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','yourmysqlusername','yourmysqlpassword','youmysqldatabase');
$query="select * from nameofyourmysqldatabase where country='$country' && region='$region';
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query)
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
//data you want to display from your database
$data=$row['data'];
echo $data;
}

?>
```

well it's just an example you need to do lot css,php,jquery,html works but i hope you understand the basic behind it

Comment: [Don't check for `isset` *and* `!empty`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty/4559976#4559976)

Comment: well it's just an example to show him but i think if both the countryname and region are filled in than it better choice to use it