# Is there a php function which returns whether the query string is empty?

Tags: php, html

I'm designing a semi-basic tool in php, I have more experience server side, and not in php.

My tool contains 10-15 pages, and I am doing the navigation between them with the $_GET parameter.

I would like to check if the query string is empty (to know if I'm in the home page). Is there any php function for this ? Of course I can do it manually, but still?

EDIT: My question is if there is a function that replaces

```
if(! isset("param1") && .....&& ! isset("paramN")){
...
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: use isset() or empty()

Comment: You can check if form data is posted or not `if($_GET)` (replace it by `$_POST` if you're using post method, I believe that is what you're asking ?

Comment: that's the problem, my architecture looks wrong because I dont wanna do if (isset[param1] && .....isset(param[n])....

Comment: is your goal to check if the query string is completely empty? So that there are no $_GET variables at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
if(isset($_GET['YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME']) && !empty($_GET['YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME'])) {

}
```

`isset()` is used to check whether there is any such variable or not

`empty()` to check whether the variable is not empty or not

As per your comment, assume your URL as below

```
http://192.168.100.68/stack/php/get.php?id=&name=&action=delete&type=category
```

And your PHP script as below

```
<?php

$qs = $_GET;
$result = '';
foreach($qs as $key=>$val){
    if(empty($val)){
        $result .= 'Query String \''.$key.'\' is empty. <br />';
    }
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
?>
```

In my above URL I passed `id` and `name` as empty.

Hence, Result will be like below

> id is empty.
>   name is empty.

but I dont think its standard way.

If you want to process something only if all parameters are having some values, they you can move those process inside a `if` as below

```
if(empty($result)) {
     // YOUR PROCESS CODE GOES HERE
} else {
     echo 'Some Required Parameters are missing. Check again';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there some function that returns empty() for ANY variable of the query string?

Comment: thank you again, yes it's interesting, but I said I could do it manually, and wanted to know if there is a php function for this. gave you an upvote :)

Comment: @wp42 upto my knowledge no such functions. Thanks for ur +1. I didn't guessed this is what you meant by manual.

Comment: I think you are right, and there is no such function, so I will accept this answer.

Comment: @wp42 thanks. If I get update on this in future will update you too

Comment: why combining isset and empty? Php empty functions also checks whether a variable is set....

Comment: @shock_gone_wild refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty

Comment: @anto.nishanth well... the accepted answer supports my comment? ;)

Comment: @shock_gone_wild I didn't get you

Comment: i want to say there is no need to combine isset() and ! empty(). the question you posted in a previous comment supports this.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild I couldn't say correctly but in my earlier stage i faced issue when I am using only !empty() when there is no such parameter at all, May be its depends on php version