# Rewrite GET in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try to RewriteRule my GET variables. I searched many sites but none of the .htacces rewrites seem to work.

I like to rewrite the following URL:

http://www.uniquetravelling.nl/reis-info?reis=ijsland

to:

http://www.uniquetravelling.nl/reis-info/reis/ijsland

I use the following RewriteRules to filter at least my .php of every file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
Header add "disablevcache" "true"
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
IndexIgnore *
```

This is how I call the URL link

```
<a class="mobile-link-reisaanbod" href="http://www.uniquetravelling.nl/reis-info?reis=ijsland">meer info...</a>
```

This is how I retrieve the GET variable from the URL

```
if(!isset($_GET['reis']) || empty($_GET['reis'])){
    header('Location: 404');
} else {
    $reis = strtolower($_GET['reis']);
}
```

Can someone help me with the rewrite code specific for my website?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tangentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/476