# Should you use htmlspecialchars() before isset() and empty(), or after?

Tags: php

I was wondering what is the correct procedure when it comes to security and practicality. Should you use htmlspecialchars() on a variable before you check if it's set and empty?

Examples:

Use htmlspecialchars() on use or storage of post data:

```
$field = $_POST['field'];
if(isset($field)){
    //store or use: htmlspecialchars($field);
}
```

Or should you use htmlspecialchars() on retrieval of the post data:

```
$field = htmlspecialchars($_POST['field']);
if(isset($field)){
    //store or use: $field
}
```

This is probably a silly question, but I wanted to know which is correct.

Comment: First one is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, think about it this way. Why do we use `isset` in the first place? The answer is to protect our code from trying to do things with something that doesn't exist.

For example, using `php -a` in your console, you can see:

```
php > $temp
php > echo htmlspecialchars($temp);

Parse error: parse error in php shell code on line 2
php >
```

Clearly you don't want your code throwing parse errors. So, you need to check that the value exists first (using `isset`), then do things with that value.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I was told to always use htmlspecialchars() when retrieving field information, wasn't sure if it was correct either way. I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: @KaveElite yes, always make sure to sanitize information you receive from "the outside". But first make sure you got something in the first place :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use both isset and empty if you want to make your condition fully secure, Because isset checks that variable is defined or not and empty checks for the value of variable is empty or not.
So you should use your if condition like this,

```
$field = $_POST['field'];
if(isset($field) && !empty($field)){
    //store or use: htmlspecialchars($field);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. The endpoint might legitimately be expecting a `FALSE` value and the above will not accept that.

Comment: [This has been discussed already on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)