# if statement on session data codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

So I am trying to hide or show options if the user is logged in or not.

I have this simple statement, its always showing **no** regardless if I am logged in or not.

```
if( !isset($_SESSION) ){
                    echo "yes";
                }
                else {
                    echo "no";
                }
```

I have also tried

```
function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->is_logged_in();
}


    if(is_logged_in())

        {
            echo "yes";
        }

    else
    {
        echo "no";                      
    }
```

Neither works, I also think the first one if simpler, but I am not sure what method would be better.

Comment: did you set your session ?? when user logged in ..

Comment: I would suggest codeigniter's session class, its a bit more robust IMHO: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Ok thank you, Ill have a read +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset($_SESSION)` checks if the variable is set or not and here `$_SESSION` is already defined.

so in your case `!(isset($_SESSION))` is `false` coz `isset($_SESSION)` is true and `!true` is `false`

To check for the session value try `isset($_SESSION['key_you_set'])`. This will check if the `key_you_set` exists or not.

Comment: Ok thank you, so using session data like this wont give me the result i need

Comment: try like isset($_SESSION['key_you set'])

Comment: And would be better trying CI's session library. :)

Comment: like `if $this->session->userdata('id'); {echo "yes";}`

Comment: like if($this->session->userdata('id')) {echo "yes";} after saving userdata with key id

Comment: Got ya, Thank you dude, your a star.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set an session with name **session_id**
You can retrieve your session  information in codeigniter like,

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

Now You can check like below

```
if($session_id==""){
echo "session not set";
}
else{
echo "session set";
}
```

Comment: = will assign value to the variable so your expression will always return true

Comment: @NabinKunwar yeah, thats what im thinking

Comment: sorry that was an typo mistake .. i have updated my answer ..
@NabinKunwar thank you for reminding..

Answer (score -1):

### I think this helps you ..

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

### less code but more secure

```
echo (!empty($session_id ) && isset($session_id) ) ? "session set" : "session not set" ;  // ternary operator
```

Comment: `!empty($var) && isset($var)` is an antipattern that no one should ever use in any project for any reason.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403