# PHP: Adding input from HTML form to exisiting PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I would like to create a PHP class that takes the inputted data from a HTML form and adds it to an existing php array `$profileArray` that can then be included in my filter `for` and `if` loops.

My existing hardcoded data is filtered by `'Age'` depending on the choice made in the first form with `radio` buttons. My question is, how can I used the php class to add the input to the hardcoded database `$profileArray` and then include it in the filter by `Age`.

## HTML

```
<html>

<body>
<p>Please choose at least one quality you would like in your new cat: </p>
        <form action="profileFilter.php" method="POST">
    <p>Age: <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ageChoice" value="1">1 <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ageChoice" value="2">2 <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ageChoice" value="3">3<br>
            <input type="submit" name="submitButton">   
    </form>

<p>Submit your own cat for adoption: </p>
        <form action="profileData.class.php" method="GET">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="inputData[Name]" placeholder="What name?"></p>
    <p>Age: <input type="text" name="inputData[Age]" placeholder="What age?"></p>
    <p>Colour: <input type="text" name="inputData[Colour]" placeholder="What Colour?"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="catQualitiesBtn">   
    </form>

</body></html>
```

## Main PHP File:

```
    <?php
//Acting as hardcoded database
$profileArray = array( 
array(  'Name' => "Toby",
        'Age' => 3, 
        'Colour' => "Ginger",
        ),

array(  'Name' => "Cassie",
        'Age' => 3, 
        'Colour' => "Tabby",
        ),

array(  'Name' => "Lucy",
        'Age' => 1, 
        'Colour' => "Black",
        ),

array(  'Name' => "Rufus",
        'Age' => 2, 
        'Colour' => "White",
        ),
);

if (isset ($_POST['ageChoice']) && !empty($_POST['ageChoice'])) {
    $passedAgeChoice = $_POST['ageChoice'];
    echo $passedAgeChoice."<br>";
    for ($i=0; $i < 7 ; $i++) { 

           if ($profileArray[$i]['Age'] == $passedAgeChoice) {
            echo " Name: ".$profileArray[$i]['Name']."<br>";
            echo " Age: ".$profileArray[$i]['Age']."<br>";
            echo " Colour: ".$profileArray[$i]['Colour']."<br>";
            echo " Gender: ".$profileArray[$i]['Gender']."<br>";
            echo " Personality: ".$profileArray[$i]['Personality']."<br>"."<br>";}
        }
}
else {
    $passedAgeChoice = NULL;
    echo "***YOU HAVE NOT ENTERED AN AGE***"." <br>";
} 
}


///This is where I am having trouble///
$inputtedData = $_GET['inputData[]']; 

$inputDataArrayObject = new InputDataArray;
$inputDataArrayObject->setFormDataInput($inputtedData);
$inputDataArrayObjectArray= $inputDataArrayObject->getFormDataInput();
 echo "The data you inputted is ". $inputtedData."<br>";
       ?>
```

## PHP Class File:

```
class InputDataArray {

private $formDataInput;


public function setFormDataInput($x){
    $this->formDataInput=$x;
}

public function getFormDataInput(){
    return $this->formDataInput;
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: you should be able to add to the array by parsing the input data, creating an array like in your $profileArray definition (e.g. $temp = array ('Name' = $whateverYouParsed)) and adding that array to the $profileArray using array_push

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Thank you, I have tried to understand the array_push and this is what I have done so far [HERE](https://codeshare.io/aj0un). But perhaps you could explain a bit more how to approach this? Going by the tutorials I have watched it seems it is what I am looking for but I can't understand how to implement it.

Comment: Anyone writing `isset ($_POST['ageChoice']) && !empty($_POST['ageChoice'])` needs to read [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/2943403)