# PHP: Shorthand or function for if(!isset($array['index']) || empty($array['index']))?

Tags: php, arrays, isset, is-empty

I make a lot of SOAP calls to external services in PHP, and sometimes the XML I get back provides a field, sometimes it provides that field, but empty, and sometimes it just doesn't provide it at all.  So every time I want to store a value, I have to wrap it like so:

`$age = (isset($person['age']) && !empty($person['age'])) ? $person['age'] : NULL;`

I thought I could simply make a function to do that, or call `empty()` alone, but as soon as I do that without the `isset` check first, I get a call to an undefined index when the XML I get back lacks the `age` index.

Is there a shorthand way of checking BOTH `isset` and `empty`?  Or some function I can build myself which won't result in this warning (but still will give me any others, in case there are REAL problems)?

Comment: `!empty($person['age'])` should work. But `empty` will return `true` for `0` & `false` also. Are you sure the error is on same line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty

Comment: My mistake; I thought `empty($person['age'])` was returning a warning when not set.  Apparently I was mistaken!