# replace not session_is_registered() with not isset($_SESSSION)?

Tags: php, session-cookies

I was working in a login system `session_is_registered` but this function doesnt work in `php5.4+` so I replaced:

```
   if (session_is_registered('id_user') == true && session_is_registered ('username') == true){}
```

to

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id_user']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])){}
```

...and it works.

But what happens if a want to replace (becouse I need to use this expression)

```
if (!session_is_registered('id_user') || !session_is_registered('username')){}
```

Do I need to use `!isset()`  or `empty()`?

Comment: You should probably use both !isset and empty() for both id_user and username

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty

Comment: @Brett what you mean is this? `if  ((!isset($_SESSION['id_user'])  && empty($_SESSION['id_user']) || (!isset($_SESSION['usernamer'])  && empty($_SESSION['username'])){}` ? are you sure of this?

Comment: return error using both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this way

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id_user']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      /* this will true if both are set */
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['id_user']) || !isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      /* this will true if one of them is not set */
}
```

> isset will give true if variable is set
>   empty will give true if variable is set and its blank or null
>
> isset() is NOT equivalent to empty().

Comment: thanks you, please help me with this expression `if ((!isset($_SESSION['id_user']) && empty($_SESSION['id_user']) || (!isset($_SESSION['usernamer']) && empty($_SESSION['username'])){}` would be correct?

Comment: try this it's more safe to use `if (!isset($_SESSION['id_user']) || empty($_SESSION['id_user']) || 
 !isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])){/* this means user is not login */ }`