# Filter array of strings and retain elements containing one of many keywords

Tags: php, filter, keyword

I currently have the code all done to filter by one keyword, but I'm wanting to filter by 100+ keywords. I'm not experienced enough in PHP, so I've tried and failed.

Here is my current code but I'm wanting to modify it to use multiple keywords.

```
function postResolve ($key) {
    return isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : null;
}

$formData = [
    'keyword' => postResolve('keyword'),
    'text'    => postResolve('text')
];

if (is_null($formData['keyword']) || is_null($formData['text'])) {
    return 'Nothing to do... Missing text or keyword.';
}

$text = explode(PHP_EOL, $formData['text']);

$storage = [];

foreach ($text as $sentence) {
    if (strpos($sentence, $formData['keyword']) !== false) {
        $storage[] = trim($sentence);
    }
}

echo json_encode($storage);
```

Would appreciate if someone could give me a hand on this change :)

Comment: if you're using PHP 7, `isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : null` equals `$_POST[$key] ?? null`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure PHP is by far my most hated language, I had a friend do this for me. I just modified it to work with bootstrap.

Comment: You can use in_array and place the 100+ keywords in your haystack.

Comment: How are you getting the multiple keywords? Are they in an array?

Comment: @Dzje I am not sure where that came from, PHP is used by at least 50% of the webservers and used by a lot of popular websites.

Comment: Okay so this is just the functionality, i have an index.php that has 1 textbox to enter the keywords in, another multi line text box which will be full with stuff that im wanting to fillter and then there is a button that obviously filters the keywords and removes the rest. So I'll be entering the keywords manually in the text box like example "keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4" and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) instead of `strpos()`. Unlike the `strpos()`, `stripos()` is case-insensitive. Treat your keywords as an array. Let's assume they are comma-delimited:

```
<?php
    function postResolve ($key) {
        return isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : NULL;
    }

    function checkKeywords($sentence, $keywords) {
        foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
            if(stripos($sentence, $keyword) !== FALSE) { return TRUE; }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {

        $formData = array(
            'keywords' => postResolve('keywords'),
            'text'    => postResolve('text')
        );

        if(is_null($formData['keywords']) || is_null($formData['text'])) {
            echo 'Nothing to do... Missing text or keyword.';
        }

        $text = explode(PHP_EOL, $formData['text']);
        $keywords = explode(',', $formData['keywords']);

        $storage = array();

        foreach($text as $sentence) {
            if(checkKeywords($sentence, $keywords)) {
                $storage[] = trim($sentence);
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($storage);
        exit();
    }
?>

<form>
    <textarea name="keywords"></textarea>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('div').load(location.href, $('form').serializeArray());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So lets say for example I'm wanting to filter just two keywords "07883, 07886" the two keywords a separated by the comma and that would work?

Comment: 07883,07886 would work unless you explode using ", " as your delimiter. You could always explode on the comma and use an array_map to trim the keywords in case there is a space after the comma. Or just explode on PHP_EOL and have the keywords placed each on a new line like you are doing your text.

Comment: yeah that didn't filter, it just resulted in the filtered box returning blank :(

Comment: @Dzje paste that entire script into a blank document and it will work.

Comment: this is the code for my index.php http://pastebin.com/raw/yWd8ptKc is there any chance to get it working with this?

Comment: You sir are a very nice guy, much appreciated.

Comment: `isset() && !empty()` is an antipattern which should not exist in any code for any reason.  [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403)