# How get data from MySQL database by specific id in url

Tags: php, mysql

How i can get data from MySQL database by specific id in url

#### Url

http://localhost/php/edit_student.php?id=11

#### My function

```
function selected_students($connect){
$sentence = $connect->prepare('SELECT students.student_name, students.student_thumbnail FROM students JOIN courses_students ON courses_students.student_id = students.student_id JOIN courses ON courses_students.course_id = courses'.$_GET['id'].'GROUP BY courses_students.student_id');
$sentence->execute(array());
return $sentence->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: what error you are facing,

Comment: error : `$sentence->execute(array());`

Comment: (1) Your code is wide open to SQL injection.  (2) In what way is your code failing?

Comment: You would run into problem of sql injection by directly passing query param into sql query. You should use the recommended way for eg. use of `bindParam()` method...

Comment: how is your id field data in the database? is it a string or int?

Comment: It's working when id is (courses_students.course_id = 10) but with $_get['id'] not working

Comment: try `courses_students.course_id = '.$_GET['id'].' GROUP ` but i won't recommend it. too unsecure

Comment: Your query reads like : 1`ON courses_students.course_id = courses'.10`.

Comment: (1) Why? (2) i cant get id by $_GET['id'] @David

Comment: @bdroid before u use `$_GET[]` u need to check if id isset and not empty

Comment: @SagarGuhe HOW?

Comment: @bdroid: (1) Google "PHP SQL injection" to learn more.  Basically, you're allowing users to execute any code they want on your database by putting user input directly in your SQL code.  (2) Why can't you?  What's stopping you?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile how please ?

Comment: @bansi not working ;(

Comment: @bdroid you can google about sql injection and will get lot of information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned you need to check if the `$_GET['id']` isset and is not empty in the comments, and also when u using `prepare()` you must not inject a variable direct into your query you must use placeholder, then bind and execute. PDO have two types of placeholders which are `:PlaceHolderName` and `?`

```
 <?php
    function selected_students($connect)
    {

        if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {

            $id = intval($_GET['id']);

            $sentence = $connect->prepare("SELECT students.student_name,students.student_id,students.student_thumbnail,courses_students.student_id,courses.course_id from students,courses join courses_students on students.student_id = courses_students.student_id and courses.course_id = ? GROUP BY courses_students.student_id");
            $sentence->execute([$id]);

            $results = $sentence->fetchall();

            if ($results > 0) {
                // Results exists display them



            }


        } else {

            // return error the id is not set
        }


    }
    ?>
```

Here are the good places where u can learn pdo

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html

Comment: in (?) i want to get the id from url(...edit_student.php?id=11) like this (SELECT students.student_name,students.student_id,students.student_thumbnail,courses_students.student_id,courses.course_id from students,courses join courses_students on students.student_id = courses_students.student_id and courses.course_id = 11 GROUP BY courses_students.student_id)

Comment: `?` is a placeholder for the id.... comment out all your code and type `var_dump($_GET['id']);` tell m what u get

Comment: i get this: string(2) "11"

Comment: good, can u update u question with the latest code u have and also do include your database

Comment: I need to see the code u currently have so I can be able to knw where the error is

Comment: I resolve it with: $id = $_GET['id']; $sentence = $connect->prepare("SELECT students.student_name,students.student_id,students.student_thumbnail,courses_students.student_id,courses.course_id from students,courses join courses_students on students.student_id = courses_students.student_id and courses.course_id = ".$id); $results = $sentence->fetchall(); but i cant add GROUP BY...

Comment: `courses.course_id = ".$id); ` should be `courses.course_id = ?); ` then `$sentence->execute([$id]);`

Comment: i get error with your code PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in functions.php on line 230

Comment: its working with: if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) { $id = intval($_GET['id']); $sentence = $connect->prepare("SELECT students.student_name,students.student_id,students.student_thumbnail,courses_students.student_id,courses.course_id from students,courses join courses_students on students.student_id = courses_students.student_id and courses.course_id = ? GROUP BY courses_students.student_id"); $sentence->execute([$id]); $results = $sentence->fetchall(); }}

Comment: yes that should work if the answer helped u may upvote and accpt

Comment: `isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])` should not exist in any code for any reason. [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403)