# PHP tests and conditional

Tags: php

With this code I'm trying to display an event date that has a beginning and ending date, but sometimes there is only one beginning date.

If there is a beginning and ending date i need this displayed:
 **DU 10 JUILLET 2017 AU 10 JUILLET 2017**

And if there is only a beginning date, i need this displayed:
 **LE 10 JUILLET 2017** (the "DU" is replace by "LE")

```
<?php if (isset($this->item->jcfields[3]) && !empty($this->item-jcfields[3])): 
?>Du
<?php echo FieldsHelper::render('com_content.article', 'field.render', 
array('field'=> $this->item->jcfields[3])); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (isset($this->item->jcfields[7]) && !trim($this->item-
>jcfields[7])): ?>Au
<?php echo FieldsHelper::render('com_content.article', 'field.render', 
array('field'=> $this->item->jcfields[7])); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: can you reformat? it might just be me, but that code is next to impossible to read

Comment: Aside: [Why check both isset and !empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/476)

Comment: sorry i am newbie in PHP

Comment: 1. Check if the end date is set, output either DU or LE accordingly. 2. Output the formatted start date - not conditions necessary. 3. Check again if end date is set - if so, outout AU and the formatted end date.

Comment: I do not know how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, and I tried to keep your code the same while improving formatting.

```
<?php
if (isset($this->item->jcfields[3]) && !empty($this->item->jcfields[3]) && $this->item->jcfields[3]->value != ''):
    if (isset($this->item->jcfields[7]) && !empty($this->item->jcfields[7]) && $this->item->jcfields[7]->value != ''):
        echo "Du ";
    else:
        echo "Le ";
    endif;
    echo FieldsHelper::render('com_content.article', 'field.render', array('field'=> $this->item->jcfields[3]));
    if (isset($this->item->jcfields[7]) && !empty($this->item->jcfields[7]) && $this->item->jcfields[7]->value != ''):
        echo " Au ";
        echo FieldsHelper::render('com_content.article', 'field.render', array('field'=> $this->item->jcfields[7]));
    endif;
endif;
```

Comment: This work when there is begin and ending date but when there is no ending date the disaply is DU 10 JUILLET 2017 AU
Thanks.

Comment: samr problem when end date is empty DU 6 JUILLET 2017 AU. var dump https://pastebin.com/DBKJsU6X

Comment: Yes it work but now when there is no ending date the display is like this LE 1 SEPTEMBRE 2017 AU the AU need to be disable, thanks.