# PHP ZEND $_GET Gives Undefined Index

Tags: php, zend-framework, get

So I'm editing one of my company's websites. I am not all too familiar with the way Zend works, but I haven't had good luck finding a solution to this problem.

We have two different sites, a staging website which I freely edit and test on, and a live version that the public can view. When I created a new controller/view, I used $_GET data to handle some forms. It worked as expected on the testing end, but the production end for some reason didn't work. After a bit of testing, I found out that the $_GET data is not actually being sent, and thus my script would boot me out (as it is designed to).

The URL looks sorta like this:

```
/admin/something/update?data=20
```

So I check the $_GET as I usually do:

```
if ( isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET["data"]) ) {
  // do something
} else {
  // redirect the user
}
```

It always redirects like it should if there is no $_GET data (and if data doesn't contain a value).

So I debug and find out that this is what $_GET looks like after I print_r and all I get is an empty array despite the URL clearly containing the $_GET data.

It might be my limited knowledge of Zend handles GET and POST data (because I pretty much keep my edits to old-school PHP), so any light to this would be fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know ZF, but if I had to guess I would say that either your mod_rewrite rules don't have the `QSA` flag and so query string items aren't being forwarded or that ZF does something with $_GET, overwrites it and then expects you to use some method to fetch that data.

Comment: [You don't need to check both `isset() && !empty()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty).

Comment: `$_GET` as other **superglobals** is always\ available, so checking if it exists is pointless

Comment: I've been using isset() and !empty() for virtually everything, so even when it comes to dealing with the superglobals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some problem into your .htaccess file.
May be some additional rewrite rule for SEO.

you can add and try with, either should work,

```
RewriteRule . index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Or,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

and for getting get value, you should use,

```
 if(isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data']){
            var_dump($_GET['data']);exit;
        }
```

Comment: It was the rewrite rules. I recently got promoted to working with commercial websites so it's all a bit foreign to me.