# Checking if array item is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

`$fields_data`, which outputs:

```
Array ( [name] => [email] => [phone] => [message] => )
```

and `$required_fields_array`, which outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => name [1] => email [2] => message )
```

The values of `$required_fields_array`, are items in the `$fields_data array`.

I need to check each of the `$required_fields_array` against the `$fields_data` to check if the array item they correspond to is empty.

I have tried:

```
foreach( $required_fields_array as $key ) 
{                                       
    if ( isset($fields_data[$key]) === false && empty($fields_data[$key]) === true  )       
    {               
        print_r('empty');
    }           
}
```

I can't see why the above isn't working.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Remove the isset part. The fact that a variable is defined doesn't mean it is not empty

Comment: You're saying *if the value is not set __and__ it's empty*. You probably want an *or* there. And then you don't need the `isset` at all.

Comment: Remove === false === true from both isset and empty, bcoz if its either empty or not set your condition will return true and it goes in if

Comment: Keep it as if ( isset($fields_data[$key])  && !empty($fields_data[$key]) ) , your code if fine otherwise

Comment: @shashi [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/476)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$fields_data = Array ( 'name' => '','email' => '','phone' => '','message' => '');
//Added extra element `asd` to show that `isset()` is not required
$required_fields_array = Array ('name','email',' message', 'asd');
foreach( $required_fields_array as $key ) 
{
    if(empty($fields_data[$key]))       
    {               
        print_r('empty');
    }           
}
```

Remove the `isset` and `=== false` etc. Because, `empty()` will do the `isset()`'s job too.