# How to convert $_SESSION['myarray'] to regular PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, session

So I have declared a Session array and initialized it with zeroes. It's basically a multidimensional array. However, I'm thinking of converting it to a regular array because everytime I test whether a value exists or not using the `in_array()` function, it fails. It keeps adding existing values.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['numbers'] = array(
        array(0,0,0,0,0), //row1
        array(0,0,0,0,0), //row2
        array(0,0,0,0,0), //row3
        array(0,0,0,0,0), //row4
        array(0,0,0,0,0) //row5
    );
?>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST["num"]) && !empty($_POST["num"])){
        $userInput = $_POST["num"];
        for($r = 0; $r<sizeof($_SESSION['numbers']); $r++){
            for($c = 0; $c<sizeof($_SESSION['numbers']); $c++){
                $colVal = $_SESSION['numbers'][$r][$c];
                    insertInputAt($r,$c,$userInput);    
            }
        }
    }

    function insertInputAt($row,$col,$input){
        if(!in_array($input, $_SESSION['numbers'])){ //this fails
            echo $input . "<br/>";
            $_SESSION['numbers'][$row][$col] = $input;
        }
    }
?>
```

If I enter lets say **5**, it inserts the input **5** to all rows and columns. I get **25** echos of value of **5** even if I put a `!in_array()` condition

I thought maybe if I parse the `$_SESSION['numbers]` as a regular array **within** the `insertInputAt()` method, the `!in_array()` condition might work accurately.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are going to use `in_array` you will need to select to correct "child" array with your `$row` param:  `in_array($input, $_SESSION['numbers'][$ow])`

Comment: `$r` & `$c` would have `0,1,2,3,4`. Also `in_array()` wont work for multidimensional `array`s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting and replacing values to multidimensional array when it exists or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495969/inserting-and-replacing-values-to-multidimensional-array-when-it-exists-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `insertInputAt` function to this:

```
function insertInputAt($row,$col,$input){
    if(!in_array($input, $_SESSION['numbers'][$row])){ //this fails
        echo $input . "<br/>";
        $_SESSION['numbers'][$row][$col] = $input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to initialize `$_SESSION['numbers']`.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$userInput = $_POST["num"] = 1;
for($r=0;$r<count($_SESSION['numbers']);$r++){
    $found = 0;
    for($c=0;$c<count($_SESSION['numbers'][$r]);$c++){
        if(($_SESSION['numbers'][$r][$c]==0)&&(myfunction($_SESSION['numbers'],$userInput)==0)){
            $_SESSION['numbers'][$r][$c] = $userInput;unset($_POST['num']); $found=1;break;
        }
    }
    if($found==1)break;
}

function myfunction($array,$value){
    foreach($array as $q){
        if(!in_array($value,$q)){
            for($i=0;$i<count($q);$i++){
                if($q[$i]==0) return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION['numbers']);
?>
```