# How to check user textbox is empty effectively?

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to make a PHP form and check that text boxes are empty. My code:

```
<form method="post"> 
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
```

```
//check user that fill in blank
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
   $nameErr = "Name is required";
   }
```

Is this an effective way to check that the user filled in the blank?
If user type "0", the system shows an error message.

Does anyone have a more efficient way?

Comment: Try !isset OR empty()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If user type "0", the system shows an error message

Make use of `filter_var()`, and more precisely `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`.

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

See the comments inside:

```
$input = 0; // is an integer and will not echo

if(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false){
  echo "The input is not an integer";
}

$input = "0"; // is an integer and will not echo

if(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false){
  echo "The input is not an integer";
}

$input = "text"; // is NOT an integer and will echo

if(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false){
  echo "The input is not an integer";
}

$input = "text123"; // is NOT an integer and will echo

if(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false){
  echo "The input is not an integer";
}
```

As for your:

> Is this an effective way to check that the user filled in the blank?

- `empty()` does work well here, as `isset()` is more effective with radio/checkboxes.

Have a look at the following and the differences between both:

- [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the following values are considered to be "**[`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)**":

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
```

As such, when validating that a variable actually contains data, you'll also want to check **[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)** in addition to `empty()`:

```
if (empty($_POST["name"]) || !isset($_POST["name"])) {
  $nameErr = "Name is required";
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: "0" would still trigger your error

Answer (score 0):

You could use `trim()`, which deletes whitespace at the beginning or end, so it will also delete a single whitespace

```
if (empty(trim($_POST["name"]))) {
  $nameErr = "Name is required";
}
```

or (to avoid the "0" problem)

```
if (trim($_POST["name"]) !== "") {
  $nameErr = "Name is required";
}
```