# How to change a variable outside an "if" clause

Tags: php

I am still a student and new to PHP and web development in general.
I wanted to update the $f1 variable via a button but i could not seem to do it. Is there something that I have been missing?

I have tried the following (simplified) code:

```
<?php

$f1="s";

//user presses a button to change the variable
if(isset($_POST['emp_sig']) && !empty($_POST['emp_sig'])){

$upload_dir1 = "signatures/EmployeeSignatures/";
$file1= $upload_dir1 . mktime() . ".png";
$GLOBALS['f1'] = $file1;
$success = file_put_contents($file1, $data1);
print $success ? $file1 : 'Unable to save the file.';


}


//user now presses another button to echo the updated variable
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


echo $GLOBALS['f1'];

}

?>
```

It does not echo an updated variable but it echoes "s". Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are under the impression that $GLOBALS would hold values across different script instances …? Nope, it doesn’t. Most likely you want to look into _sessions_.

Comment: The most obvious reason is that it doesn't enter the code block where modification happens.

Comment: To begin with, no need to do `if(isset($_POST['emp_sig']) && !empty($_POST['emp_sig'])){`, you can only do `if(!empty($_POST['emp_sig'])){` because `empty` test if it's isset + if not null, empty, etc.

Comment: Actually, not using $GLOBALS and directly updating the $f1 variable was my first solution, it did not solve the problem. Actually, the first if{} block uploads a .png file to my server, and updates the $f1 variable. No problem with uploading, but it fails to update the variable. It really is puzzling me.

Comment:  [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/476)

Comment: Here's a link to the manual for [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). You need to read it and use them to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use globals, you can directly access the variable.

```
$f1="s";

//user presses a button to change the variable
if(!empty($_POST['emp_sig'])){
    $upload_dir1 = "signatures/EmployeeSignatures/";
    $file1= $upload_dir1 . mktime() . ".png";
    $f1 = $file1;
    $success = file_put_contents($file1, $data1);
    print $success ? $file1 : 'Unable to save the file.';
}

//user now presses another button to echo the updated variable
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $f1;
}
```

Comment: I have been there. That was my first solution. Does not work.

Comment: What does "_does not work_" mean? No output? Wrong output?

Comment: it does not update the $f1 variable. It outputs "s". The first if{} block actually uploads an image to my server, and updates the variable. It successfully uploads the image to my server but it fails to update the variable. What is happening.

Comment: can you post the html code that you are using for this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Using $_SESSION solved my problem.

```
<?php

session_start();

//user presses a button to change the variable
if(!empty($_POST['emp_sig'])){

$upload_dir1 = "signatures/EmployeeSignatures/";
$file1= $upload_dir1 . mktime() . ".png";
$_SESSION["path1"] = $file1;
$success = file_put_contents($file1, $data1);
print $success ? $file1 : 'Unable to save the file.';


}


//user now presses another button to echo the updated variable
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


echo $f1 = $_SESSION["path1"];

}

?>
```

Thank you for all those who helped