# Getting stuck in (php) foreach mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli, foreach

I'm trying to code a php page that checks if the `$_GET['uuid']` matches the value in the database and if the ip address of the current visitor matches the ip address of `$_GET['uuid']` stored in the database.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['uuid'])){
    $uuid = $_GET['uuid'];
    include('database.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ips`"; 
    $sql2 =  "SELECT * FROM `ips` WHERE `uuid` =  '". $uuid ."'";
    foreach($mysqli->query($sql) as $row){
        $ipss = $row;
    }
    foreach($mysqli->query($sql2) as $ipsrrr){
        $ipsr = $ipsrrr;
    }
    if($ipss['uuid'] == $uuid && $ipsr['ip'] == $gip){
            $allowed = 1;
    }else{
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit(0);
    }
}else{
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit(0);
}
```

I don't known why but i get stuck in the foreach loop. I get a blank page with an loading icon.

Comment: You not outputting anything surely you will get a blank page

Comment: `$gip`  is undefined there. as well as add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` on top of your code script to get possible errors.

Comment: Why do you make two queries, once to fetch ***all*** IP rows, and once to fetch just the ones where `uuid` matches (which seems more sensible)?! Secondly, you're looping over the results and assign to `$ipss` and `$ipsr`, but you're overwriting those variables and only the last row will stick there. This all makes very little sense. You should just do *one* query `WHERE  uuid = $uuid AND ip = $gip`, and either you get a result or you don't. No need to loop anything or compare something again in PHP.

Comment: what is the `$gip` variable ? that you used to equal?

Comment: First sorry, that have not post the whol code

Comment: $gip is a return of a function that get's the ip form user

Comment: In addition to the unneeded second query, you should parameterize your query.

Comment: @getServer you can't ask people to register somewhere just to help you.

Comment: @Alberto i never asked people to register somewhere - if you click the link u will see there is no way to register ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$mysqli->query($sql)` returns a result set.

Try replacing each of your foreach loops with (modified for each loop)

```
$resultSet = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row = $resultSet->fetch_row())
{
    $ipss = $row;
}
```

This will retrieve the resultset, and then perform an action for each row returned.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to perform any loops. As @deceze said, you can simply query for uuid and ip, if there is a result, the user is 'allowed'. Be careful with SQL-Injections.

```
  if(!empty($_GET['uuid'])){

    // Evaluate IP and UUID.

    require_once 'database.php';

    if($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ips WHERE uuid = $uuid AND ip = $ip")){

      $allowed = 1;

    } else {

      header('Location: index.php');

    }

  } else {

    header('Location: index.php');

  }
```

Haven't tested it, but it should work.

A few things regarding to your code:

1. Instead if including it, you should require your database file.
2. You could take a look at PDO and Prepared Statements.

Comment: `$uuid` and `$ip` should probably be quoted. Mysqli has prepared statements PDO doesn't _need_ to be looked at. Possible link for mysqli doc http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: `isset && !empty` is redundant nonsense.

Comment: @deceze Its not, if the url is: `?uuid=`, `isset` will return true, but there is no uuid, therefore we need to check with `empty`.

Comment: See [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/476).

Answer (score 0):

Your code `$mysqli->query($sql)` returns an **object**, not an iterable array. To get array of fields you will need to use method `fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`. Look at example below:

```
    <?php
 $host = "localhost";
 $mysql = mysqli_connect($host, "root", "", "database");
 $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM table");
 $result = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 //parameter `MYSQLI_ASSOC` means to return associated array, 
 //(without it you will get a numeric keys for array)
 //$result[0] contains your array.
 //Now you can manipulate data:
 foreach ($result[0] as $field) {
     $get_data = $field['some_col_name'];
 }
 ?>
```