# Comparing two md5 encryption keys in PHP

Tags: php, md5

Why is it showing `incorrent password` after comparing two equal md5 keys?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['user_password']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
  $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
  echo $user_passkey = md5($user_password).'<br>';

  $filename = 'hash.txt';
  $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
  echo $file_password  = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

  if ($user_passkey==$file_password) {
    echo 'correct password';
  } else {
    echo 'Incorrect Password';
  }

} else {
  echo 'Please enter a password';
}

?>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
  Password:
  <input type="text" name="user_password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The other md5 created file is :

```
<?php 
$string = 'password';
$string_hash = md5($string);
echo $string_hash;
?>
```

The encrypted key is saved in another file named hash.txt in same folder.
echo `$user_passkey` and echo `$file_password` both are showing exact hash key(same 'password' given for both user input and previously encrypted key file hash.txt) but not getting compared in the if statement.

Why does it not work as intendet?

Comment: Why are you rolling your own password hashing thing anyway, when php [has one built in](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)?

Comment: FWIW: [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/476)

Comment: `$user_passkey = md5($user_password).'<br>';` is wrong because you added `<br>` to the hash. And then I'll bet your file contains linebreak(s). Use `trim(fread($handle, filesize($filename)))` to remove them. P.S. Consider using `json_encode` and `json_decode` to add multiple username/password logins to your file.

Answer (score 3):

It is not working, because the md5 hash you generate from the users input happens to have a `<br>` at the end, from your debug output.

1) Change

```
md5($user_password).'<br>';
```

to

```
md5($user_password);
```

2) Change

```
if ($user_passkey==$file_password)
```

to

```
if ($user_passkey==trim($file_password))
```

It will show you, that the hash is the same, because it is indeed the same hash, but the first one has the line break at the end, which makes it a different string then the other one.

Comment: If I'm removing the break line, still it is showing the same thing i.e  both keys are not equal

Comment: Also, hashing password with `md5` is absolutely __insecure__, follow https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php to know what to use instead.

Comment: Can you please do a `var_dump()` of both `$user_passkey` and `$file_password`?

Comment: Actually when using var_dump for both the variable one is showing string32 and another is showing string34 but both the encrypted key are same

Comment: @neo.abi1000 So you have a trailing newline or such in one of the strings, probably from having written it to the file with a trailing newline.

Comment: yes you are right. in the hash.txt file the key is getting trailed by a new line. what should I do?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have to use `trim()` then on the hash you get out of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i'll do

```html
<?php
$filename = 'hash.txt';
  $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
  echo $file_password  = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
  $name=md5('bimbo');
  if($name==$file_password){
   echo "string";
  }
?>
```

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['user_password']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
  $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
  $user_passkey = md5($user_password);
  $new_userpass=$user_userpass."<br/>";

  $filename = 'hash.txt';
  $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
  echo $file_password  = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

  if ($user_passkey==$file_password) {
    echo 'correct password';
  } else {
    echo 'Incorrect Password';
  }

} else {
  echo 'Please enter a password';
}

?>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
  Password:
  <input type="text" name="user_password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you can also trim your file output for whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

A md5() example

```
<?php
$str = 'apple';

if (md5($str) === '1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f') {
    echo "Would you like a green or red apple?";
}
?>
```