# What causes the error "Can't use method return value in write context" in this Codeigniter 3 application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a *Social Network* application with Codeigniter 3, **[Ion-Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth)** and Bootstrap 4. You can see the **[Github repo HERE](https://github.com/Ajax30/ci-social)**.

When editing a user's profile, I check if there is a new user photo (avatar) in the edit form. If it is, I use it, if not I use (keep) the one already existing in the `users` table (file path is `application/controllers/Auth.php`):

```
$new_file = $this->upload->data('file_name');
$this->file_name = (isset($new_file) && !empty($new_file)) ? $new_file : $user->avatar;
```

The above code works fine.

However, I need update the user's photo within the session and for this purpose I added just below `$this->file_name = (isset($new_file) && !empty($new_file)) ? $new_file : $user->avatar`:

```
if (isset($new_file) && !empty($new_file)) {
    $this->session->userdata('user_avatar') = $new_file;
}
```

The above if statement causes the error "Can't use method return value in write context".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's probably that `userdata()` returns a value, you may need to find a corresponding method to write back the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty) regarding the use of isset and empty. You do not need to use both.

```
if (isset($new_file) && !empty($new_file)) {
    $this->session->userdata('user_avatar') = $new_file;
}
```

Here you should be using  `$this->session->set_userdata('user_avatar',$new_file)` ( as per the user guide).

So it becomes

```
if (!empty($new_file)) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_avatar',$new_file);
}
```

You do not need to even consider using isset() as you are defining $new_file in your code above, so it will always be "set" i.e `isset($new_file)` will always be true.

But what do you intend to do in the case where $new_file is empty? That's a question you need to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You usually get that error in an if statement calling a method that performs write.