# Output comma separated values in foreach loop

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
  $bonusarraymain = array(

     array( "bonus1"=> "Testitem" , 
         ),
     array( "bonus2"=> "" , 
         ),
     array( "bonus3"=> "444" , 
         ),
     array( "bonus4"=> "" , 
         )
    );
```

I want to echo out the values which aren´t empty. The values should also be separated with a comma between each other. There shouldn´t be a comma after the last value.

This is how I output the values, but how can I separate them with commas?

```
          foreach ($bonusarraymain as $bonus) {
                echo $bonus['bonus1'];
                echo $bonus['bonus2']['0'];
                echo $bonus['bonus2']['1'];
                echo $bonus['bonus3'];
                echo $bonus['bonus4'];
            
       }
```

Comment: Then I have a comma after the last value. I need some check to see which value is the last so it doesn´t set a comma after this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new array with those values and use [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to insert the comma

```
foreach ($bonusarraymain as $bonus) {
      $items = array($bonus['bonus1'], 
                     $bonus['bonus2']['0'],
                     $bonus['bonus2']['1'],
                     $bonus['bonus3'],
                     $bonus['bonus4']);
      echo implode(',' , $items);            
}
```

Will leave it to you to figure out how to filter out the empty ones. Hint: `array_filter()`

Answer (score 1):

Also could use array_reduce to populate a new filtered array, then simply join the resulting array with implode.

```
<?php
$bonusarraymain = [
    [ "bonus1"=> "Testitem" ], 
    [ "bonus2"=> "" ],
    [ "bonus3"=> "444" ],
    [ "bonus4"=> "" ]
];

echo implode(', ', array_reduce($bonusarraymain, function($acc, $cur) {
    $cur = array_values($cur);
    if (isset($cur[0]) && !empty($cur[0])) $acc[] = $cur[0];
    return $acc;
}, []));
```

Result: `Testitem, 444`

Comment: `isset() && !empty()` is an antipattern that should not exist in any code for any reason.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to see what you're trying to do. Is $test supposed to be $bonus?

Update:

Use a for loop and check the index. Something like this:

```
for ($bonusId = 0; $bonusId < count($bonusarraymain); $bonusId++) {
  echo $bonus['bonus1'] . ",";
  echo $bonus['bonus2']['0'] . ",";
  echo $bonus['bonus2']['1'] . ",";
  echo $bonus['bonus3'] . ",";
  echo $bonus['bonus4'];

  if ($bonusId < count($bonusarraymain)-1) {
    echo ","
  }        
}
```

Comment: Yes, I changed it. But how can I get commas between the values execpt after the last one?

Comment: Updated my response to contain your answer.