# Update parent value from sum of children values of a json in php

Tags: php, json, function, recursion

I have a json string

```
$json = '{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Beef",
    "sector_page_id": null,
    "value": 0,
    "tree_children": [
        {
            "id": 46,
            "label": "Beef",
            "sector_page_id": null,
            "value": 0,
            "tree_children": [
                {
                    "id": 47,
                    "label": "Beef - UK",
                    "sector_page_id": null,
                    "value": 15,
                    "tree_children": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 48,
                    "label": "Beef - Europe",
                    "sector_page_id": null,
                    "value": 25,
                    "tree_children": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 49,
                    "label": "Beef - Rest of World",
                    "sector_page_id": null,
                    "value": 0,
                    "tree_children": []
                }
            ]
        }]
    }' ;
```

The sum of each `tree_children` value will be updated on parent value, So the updated json will be like this :

```
$json = '{
"id": 1,
"label": "Beef",
"sector_page_id": null,
"value": 40,
"tree_children": [
    {
        "id": 46,
        "label": "Beef",
        "sector_page_id": null,
        "value": 40,
        "tree_children": [
            {
                "id": 47,
                "label": "Beef - UK",
                "sector_page_id": null,
                "value": 15,
                "tree_children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 48,
                "label": "Beef - Europe",
                "sector_page_id": null,
                "value": 25,
                "tree_children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 49,
                "label": "Beef - Rest of World",
                "sector_page_id": null,
                "value": 0,
                "tree_children": []
            }
        ]
    }]
}' ;
```

Explanation:
[image]

My progress is not upto the mark but still want to share the snippet
[Snippet Link](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/962b4e99-5256-4077-998a-3935b3860d95)

```
$obj =  json_decode($json, 1);


    
    array_walk_recursive($obj, function(&$item, $key) use($obj){
        $sum = 0;
        
        array_walk_recursive($obj, function($item1, $key1) use (&$sum){
            if($key1 == 'value'){
                $sum += $item1;
            }
        });

        if($key == 'value'){
            if($item == 0){
                $item = $sum;
            }
        }
    });
    
    print_r($obj);
```

Comment: Array_walk_recursive only gives you the elements and no information about the level you need.
If you want a reusable solution try RecursiveArrayIterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use recursive function like below.

```
$obj =  json_decode($json, 1);

// it is important to pass the obj by reference
function recursive_sum (&$obj) {
    if ( count($obj["tree_children"]) == 0 ) {
        return $obj["value"];
    }
    // don't forget to iterate the child using pass-by-reference &
    foreach ( $obj["tree_children"] as &$_obj )
        $obj["value"] += recursive_sum($_obj);
    return $obj["value"];
}
        
recursive_sum($obj);
print_r($obj);
```

Comment: Nice and clean, Thanks! 

I have also ended up with another solution, i.e.

```function recursive_sum (&$arr, $sum = 0){
    if(isset($arr['tree_children']) && !empty($arr['tree_children'])){
        foreach($arr['tree_children'] as &$eachChild){
            $sum += $eachChild['value'];
            $arr['value'] = recursive_sum ($eachChild, $sum);
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Decoding your json as an object is ideal for this task because objects are modifiable by reference by default.  In other words, you don't need to explicitly write `&` before a variable.

There is no need to check the existence or emptiness of the relevant properties while recursing because the accessed properties in the sample data are always present.

Loop the `tree_children` in each level and add the summed value from recursing its children to its `value`.

The top level `return` will provide the grand total sum, but that value is not used by the initial function call because the `sum_recursive()` call is purely used to modify the object.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6ZCYP))

```
$obj = json_decode($json);

function sum_recursive(object $obj): int {
    foreach ($obj->tree_children as $child) {
        $obj->value += sum_recursive($child);
    }
    return $obj->value;
}
   
sum_recursive($obj);
var_export($obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

My working snippet

```
function recursive_sum (&$arr, $sum = 0){
   if(isset($arr['tree_children']) && !empty($arr['tree_children'])){
      foreach($arr['tree_children'] as &$eachChild){
        $sum += $eachChild['value'];
        $arr['value'] = recursive_sum ($eachChild, $sum);
      }
   }
   return $sum;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is missing its educational explanation. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403