# How does the empty() function works in PHP?

Tags: php

I have read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for the `empty()` function, but I'm not sure if I understood it correctly.

Is this how the `empty()` function works?:

- `empty()` will return `true` if the variable doesn't exist.
- If the variable exist, then `empty()` will return `true` if the variable is equal to `false` or if the variable is equal to `0`.
- If the variable exist and the variable is not equal to `false` and the variable is not equal to `0`, then the variable is converted to `bool` and if the result of the conversion is `false`, then `empty()` will return `true`, else `empty()` will return `false`.

Comment: What are the doubts that you have?  Can you give an example of what isn't clear to you?

Comment: The documentation _used to list_ what was considered to be `empty` beyond a variable that does not exist, but that has gone away for some reason. Anyway, the first user-provided comment at the documentation link as has the list.

Comment: @PaulT. there's a list of values that are equivalent to false at [Converting to boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). The comment omits float. The table you reference is probably the one at [PHP type comparison tables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) under _Comparisons of $x with PHP functions_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)

Comment: @MarkusAO ... yes, thanks, that is a good table comparable reference that I haven't seen in awhile. (and has likely been updated since then)

Comment: @PaulT. yeah it seems to have grown since I last saw it too. I'm wondering if there's a "PHP Manual Memory Lane" project somewhere, not the first "I'm sure it was there" effect. Digging in, [that list under `empty` was removed in 2020](https://github.com/php/doc-en/commit/3ae0b14dd06ea9d47728f366dfe2c29476a2468e) "to avoid duplication", a moot edit methinks, rather _duplicate more if it adds clarity to a manual entry_. Anyway. ^_^

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `empty()` just follows the same conversion rules that apply everywhere else in the language, I honestly think a link is a better than a copy that will eventually get out of sync. Fun fact: it's a **language construct** rather than a function; that's why it can be fed a non-existing variable and not throw an error.